# Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?

Tags: python, list, matrix, transpose

I have a list of 2-item tuples and I'd like to convert them to 2 lists where the first contains the first item in each tuple and the second list holds the second item.

**For example:**

```
original = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
# and I want to become...
result = (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Is there a builtin function that does that?

Comment: Great answers below, but also look at [numpy's transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Comment: See this nice answer to do the same with generators instead of list : [how-to-unzip-an-iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805000/how-to-unzip-an-iterator)

Comment: why is zip called a transpose?

Comment: @CharlieParker because it is analogous to a [matrix transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) in mathematics. If originally the data in each nested sequence is seen as a "row" of a matrix, its values will end up within a "column" of the corresponding matrix represented by the output.

Comment: Not an actual inverse, but in some cases `d=dict(original)` followed by `d.keys()` and `d.values()` might be convenient.

Answer (score 910, accepted):

In 2.x, [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) is its own inverse! Provided you [use the special * operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901).

```
>>> zip(*[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

This is equivalent to calling `zip` with each element of the list as a separate argument:

```
zip(('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4))
```

except the arguments are passed to `zip` directly (after being converted to a tuple), so there's no need to worry about the number of arguments getting too big.

In 3.x, `zip` [returns a lazy iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431390), but this is trivially converted:

```
>>> list(zip(*[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]))
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Oh, if only it were so simple. Unzipping `zip([], [])` this way does not get you `[], []`. It gets you `[]`. If only...

Comment: @user2357112 it give you `zip(*zip([list1], [list2]))` gives you `([list1, list2])`.

Comment: @cdhagmann: `zip([list1], [list2])` is never what you want, though. That just gives you `[(list1, list2)]`.

Comment: @user2357112 I was using `[list1]` to mean any list named list1 and not as a list with a list with only one list as an entry. 

So given `list1 = [1,2,3,4]` and `list2 = [1,2,3,4]` then `zip(*zip(list1, list2))` gives you `([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])`

Comment: @cdhagmann you get [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)] from your commands.

Comment: This does not work in Python3. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590614/python3-unzipping-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: zip does not preserve elements in longer iterables, hence padding is required

Comment: `tuple(map(list, zip(*original)))` to get precisely the mentioned result.

Comment: @Tommy This is incorrect. `zip` works exactly the same in Python 3 except that it returns an iterator instead of a list. In order to get the same output as above you just need to wrap the zip call in a list:  `list(zip(*[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]))` will output `[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]`

Comment: notice: you can meet memory and performance issues with very long lists.

Comment: It's probably a discussion for another thread, but what should you use if not lists? Should I be more concerned with quantifying "very long", and choosing or changing structures if they seem close, or preemptively using different structures for data that has the potential to scale?

Comment: @JohnP: `list`s are fine. But if you try to realize the full result all at once (by `list`ifying the result of `zip`), you might use a lot of memory (because *all* the `tuple`s must be created at once). If you can just iterate over the result of `zip` without `list`ifying, you'll save a lot of memory. The only other concern is if the input has many elements; the cost there is that it must unpack them all as arguments, and `zip` will need to create and store iterators for all of them. This is only a real problem with *very* long `list`s (think hundreds of thousands of elements or more).

Comment: This works in Python 3.9.  [Pastebin example here](https://pastebin.com/RLTv4vwf).  I have to applaud Patrick's cleverness.

Comment: In 2.x, using `zip` with `*` still doesn't quite "invert `zip`" on multiple arguments; it inverts another use *of `zip` with `*`* to unpack a single argument. `zip` inherently maps many arguments to one output which packs the transposed results together - as it must, since Python functions only return one value. The `*` unpacks, to match that packing. (Of course, in 3.x, `zip` gives an iterator instead.)

Answer (score 29):

You could also do

```
result = ([ a for a,b in original ], [ b for a,b in original ])
```

It *should* scale better. Especially if Python makes good on not expanding the list comprehensions unless needed.

(Incidentally, it makes a 2-tuple (pair) of lists, rather than a list of tuples, like `zip` does.)

If generators instead of actual lists are ok, this would do that:

```
result = (( a for a,b in original ), ( b for a,b in original ))
```

The generators don't munch through the list until you ask for each element, but on the other hand, they do keep references to the original list.

Comment: "Especially if Python makes good on not expanding the list comprehensions unless needed." mmm... normally, list comprehensions are expanded immediately - or do I get something wrong?

Comment: @glglgl: No,you're probably right. I was just hoping some future version might start doing the right thing. (It's not impossible to change, the side-effect semantics that need changes are probably already discouraged.)

Comment: What you hope to get is a generator expresion - which exists already.

Comment: No, what I hope to get is the perennial favourite "a sufficiently smarter compiler" (or interpreter in this case). I don't think there's anything sensible that would be broken by analysing the bejeebus out of the code and doing something wildly different. (like making a lazy collection) Python has never promised this feature, and will most likely never have it, but I can see that dream in the design.

Comment: This does not 'scale better' than the `zip(*x)` version. `zip(*x)` only requires one pass through the loop, and does not use up stack elements.

Comment: Whether it "scales better" or not depends of the lifecycle of the original data compared to the transposed data. This answer is only better than using `zip` if the use-case is that the transposed data is used and discarded immediately, while the original lists stay in memory for much longer.

Comment: This answer provides much better error reporting when the data is misshapen.

Answer (score 24):

I like to use `zip(*iterable)` (which is the piece of code you're looking for) in my programs as so:

```
def unzip(iterable):
    return zip(*iterable)
```

I find `unzip` more readable.

Answer (score 21):

If you have lists that are not the same length, you may not want to use zip as per Patricks answer. This works:

```
>>> zip(*[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

But with different length lists, zip truncates each item to the length of the shortest list:

```
>>> zip(*[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', )])
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')]
```

You can use map with no function to fill empty results with None:

```
>>> map(None, *[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', )])
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), (1, 2, 3, 4, None)]
```

zip() is marginally faster though.

Comment: You could also use `izip_longest`

Comment: Known as `zip_longest` for python3 users.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I know this is really old, but it's a weird built in feature: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map
"If function is None, the identity function is assumed; if there are multiple arguments, map() returns a list consisting of tuples containing the corresponding items from all iterables (a kind of transpose operation). The iterable arguments may be a sequence or any iterable object; the result is always a list."

Answer (score 18):

To get a tuple of lists, as in the question:

```
>>> original = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
>>> tuple([list(tup) for tup in zip(*original)])
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

To unpack the two lists into separate variables:

```
list1, list2 = [list(tup) for tup in zip(*original)]
```

Comment: I thnk this is the most accurate answer because, as the question asks, it actually returns a pair of lists (rather than a list of tuples).

Answer (score 7):

## Naive approach

```
def transpose_finite_iterable(iterable):
    return zip(*iterable)  # `itertools.izip` for Python 2 users
```

works fine for finite iterable (e.g. sequences like `list`/`tuple`/`str`) of (potentially infinite) iterables which can be illustrated like

```
| |a_00| |a_10| ... |a_n0| |
| |a_01| |a_11| ... |a_n1| |
| |... | |... | ... |... | |
| |a_0i| |a_1i| ... |a_ni| |
| |... | |... | ... |... | |
```

where

- `n in ℕ`,
- `a_ij` corresponds to `j`-th element of `i`-th iterable,

and after applying `transpose_finite_iterable` we get

```
| |a_00| |a_01| ... |a_0i| ... |
| |a_10| |a_11| ... |a_1i| ... |
| |... | |... | ... |... | ... |
| |a_n0| |a_n1| ... |a_ni| ... |
```

Python example of such case where `a_ij == j`, `n == 2`

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> iterable = [count(), count()]
>>> result = transpose_finite_iterable(iterable)
>>> next(result)
(0, 0)
>>> next(result)
(1, 1)
```

But we can't use `transpose_finite_iterable` again to return to  structure of original `iterable` because `result` is an infinite iterable of finite iterables (`tuple`s in our case):

```
>>> transpose_finite_iterable(result)
... hangs ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1, in ...
  File "...", line 2, in transpose_finite_iterable
MemoryError
```

So how can we deal with this case?

## ... and here comes the `deque`

After we take a look at docs of [`itertools.tee` function](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), there is Python recipe that with some modification can help in our case

```
def transpose_finite_iterables(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        first_elements = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return ()
    queues = [deque([element])
              for element in first_elements]

    def coordinate(queue):
        while True:
            if not queue:
                try:
                    elements = next(iterator)
                except StopIteration:
                    return
                for sub_queue, element in zip(queues, elements):
                    sub_queue.append(element)
            yield queue.popleft()

    return tuple(map(coordinate, queues))
```

let's check

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> iterable = [count(), count()]
>>> result = transpose_finite_iterables(transpose_finite_iterable(iterable))
>>> result
(<generator object transpose_finite_iterables.<locals>.coordinate at ...>, <generator object transpose_finite_iterables.<locals>.coordinate at ...>)
>>> next(result[0])
0
>>> next(result[0])
1
```

## Synthesis

Now we can define general function for working with iterables of iterables ones of which are finite and another ones are potentially infinite using [`functools.singledispatch` decorator](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) like

```
from collections import (abc,
                         deque)
from functools import singledispatch


@singledispatch
def transpose(object_):
    """
    Transposes given object.
    """
    raise TypeError('Unsupported object type: {type}.'
                    .format(type=type))


@transpose.register(abc.Iterable)
def transpose_finite_iterables(object_):
    """
    Transposes given iterable of finite iterables.
    """
    iterator = iter(object_)
    try:
        first_elements = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return ()
    queues = [deque([element])
              for element in first_elements]

    def coordinate(queue):
        while True:
            if not queue:
                try:
                    elements = next(iterator)
                except StopIteration:
                    return
                for sub_queue, element in zip(queues, elements):
                    sub_queue.append(element)
            yield queue.popleft()

    return tuple(map(coordinate, queues))


def transpose_finite_iterable(object_):
    """
    Transposes given finite iterable of iterables.
    """
    yield from zip(*object_)

try:
    transpose.register(abc.Collection, transpose_finite_iterable)
except AttributeError:
    # Python3.5-
    transpose.register(abc.Mapping, transpose_finite_iterable)
    transpose.register(abc.Sequence, transpose_finite_iterable)
    transpose.register(abc.Set, transpose_finite_iterable)
```

which can be considered as its own inverse (mathematicians call this kind of functions ["involutions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))) in class of binary operators over finite non-empty iterables.

---

As a bonus of `singledispatch`ing we can handle `numpy` arrays like

```
import numpy as np
...
transpose.register(np.ndarray, np.transpose)
```

and then use it like

```
>>> array = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
>>> array
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> transpose(array)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

## Note

Since `transpose` returns iterators and if someone wants to have a `tuple` of `list`s like in OP -- this can be made additionally with [`map` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) like

```
>>> original = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
>>> tuple(map(list, transpose(original)))
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

---

## Advertisement

I've added generalized solution to [`lz` package](https://pypi.org/project/lz/) from `0.5.0` version which can be used like

```
>>> from lz.transposition import transpose
>>> list(map(tuple, transpose(zip(range(10), range(10, 20)))))
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)]
```

---

## P.S.

There is no solution (at least obvious) for handling potentially infinite iterable of potentially infinite iterables, but this case is less common though.

Answer (score 4):

It's only another way to do it but it helped me a lot so I write it here:

Having this data structure:

```
X=[1,2,3,4]
Y=['a','b','c','d']
XY=zip(X,Y)
```

Resulting in:

```
In: XY
Out: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

The more pythonic way to unzip it and go back to the original is this one in my opinion:

```
x,y=zip(*XY)
```

But this return a tuple so if you need a list you can use:

```
x,y=(list(x),list(y))
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [more_itertools.unzip](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.unzip):

```
>>> from more_itertools import unzip
>>> original = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
>>> [list(x) for x in unzip(original)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous answers *efficiently* provide the required output, which is a **tuple of lists**, rather than a *list of tuples*. For the former, you can use `tuple` with `map`. Here's the difference:

```
res1 = list(zip(*original))              # [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
res2 = tuple(map(list, zip(*original)))  # (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

In addition, most of the previous solutions assume Python 2.7, where `zip` returns a list rather than an iterator.

For Python 3.x, you will need to pass the result to a function such as `list` or `tuple` to exhaust the iterator. For memory-efficient iterators, you can omit the outer `list` and `tuple` calls for the respective solutions.

Comment: this should be the top answer. it's frustrating to see the other ones that are currently considered 'top'

Answer (score 2):

While numpy arrays and pandas may be preferrable, this function imitates the behavior of `zip(*args)` when called as `unzip(args)`.

Allows for generators, like the result from `zip` in Python 3, to be passed as `args` as it iterates through values.

```py
def unzip(items, cls=list, ocls=tuple):
    """Zip function in reverse.

    :param items: Zipped-like iterable.
    :type  items: iterable

    :param cls: Container factory. Callable that returns iterable containers,
        with a callable append attribute, to store the unzipped items. Defaults
        to ``list``.
    :type  cls: callable, optional

    :param ocls: Outer container factory. Callable that returns iterable
        containers. with a callable append attribute, to store the inner
        containers (see ``cls``). Defaults to ``tuple``.
    :type  ocls: callable, optional

    :returns: Unzipped items in instances returned from ``cls``, in an instance
        returned from ``ocls``.
    """
    # iter() will return the same iterator passed to it whenever possible.
    items = iter(items)

    try:
        i = next(items)
    except StopIteration:
        return ocls()

    unzipped = ocls(cls([v]) for v in i)

    for i in items:
        for c, v in zip(unzipped, i):
            c.append(v)

    return unzipped
```

To use list cointainers, simply run `unzip(zipped)`, as

```py
unzip(zip(["a","b","c"],[1,2,3])) == (["a","b","c"],[1,2,3])
```

To use deques, or other any container sporting `append`, pass a factory function.

```py
from collections import deque

unzip([("a",1),("b",2)], deque, list) == [deque(["a","b"]),deque([1,2])]
```

(Decorate `cls` and/or `main_cls` to micro manage container initialization, as briefly shown in the final assert statement above.)

Answer (score 1):

Since it returns tuples (and can use tons of memory), the `zip(*zipped)` trick seems more clever than useful, to me.

Here's a function that will actually give you the inverse of zip.

```
def unzip(zipped):
    """Inverse of built-in zip function.
    Args:
        zipped: a list of tuples

    Returns:
        a tuple of lists

    Example:
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        b = [4, 5, 6]
        zipped = list(zip(a, b))

        assert zipped == [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

        unzipped = unzip(zipped)

        assert unzipped == ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

    """

    unzipped = ()
    if len(zipped) == 0:
        return unzipped

    dim = len(zipped[0])

    for i in range(dim):
        unzipped = unzipped + ([tup[i] for tup in zipped], )

    return unzipped
```

Comment: Continually recreating tuples doesn't seem that efficient to me but you could extend this approach using deques which could preallocate memory.

Answer (score 1):

While `zip(*seq)` is very useful, it may be unsuitable for very long sequences as it will create a tuple of values to be passed in. For example, I've been working with a coordinate system with over a million entries and find it signifcantly faster to create the sequences directly.

A generic approach would be something like this:

```
from collections import deque
seq = ((a1, b1, …), (a2, b2, …), …)
width = len(seq[0])
output = [deque(len(seq))] * width # preallocate memory
for element in seq:
    for s, item in zip(output, element):
        s.append(item)
```

But, depending on what you want to do with the result, the choice of collection can make a big difference. In my actual use case, using sets and no internal loop, is noticeably faster than all other approaches.

And, as others have noted, if you are doing this with datasets, it might make sense to use Numpy or Pandas collections instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize:

```py
# data
a = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
b = (1, 2, 3, 4)

# forward
zipped = zip(a, b)  # [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]

# reverse
a_, b_ = zip(*zipped)

# verify
assert a == a_
assert b == b_
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple one-line answer that produces the desired output:

```py
original = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
list(zip(*original))
# [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```