# Reordering matrix elements to reflect column and row clustering in naiive python

Tags: python, statistics, numpy, cluster-analysis, scipy

I'm looking for a way to perform clustering separately on matrix rows and than on its columns, reorder the data in the matrix to reflect the clustering and putting it all together. The clustering problem is easily solvable, so is the dendrogram creation (for example in [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20161027114726/http://www.janeriksolem.net:80/2009/04/hierarchical-clustering-in-python.html) or in ["Programming collective intelligence"](https://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do)). However, how to reorder the data remains unclear for me.

Eventually, I'm looking for a way of creating graphs similar to the one below using naive Python (with any "standard" library such as numpy, matplotlib etc, but without [using R](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/python/heatmap) or other external tools).

[image: dendogram]
<sub>(source: [warwick.ac.uk](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/currentstudents/peter_cock/r/heatmap/no_scaling.png))</sub>

**Clarifications**

I was asked what I meant by reordering. When you cluster data in a matrix first by matrix rows, then by its columns, each matrix cell can be identified by the position in the two dendrograms.  If you reorder the rows and the columns of the original matrix such that the elements that are close each to another in the dendrograms become close each to another in the matrix, and then generate heatmap, the clustering of the data may become evident to the viewer (as in the figure above)

Comment: I just put this up on github: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/heatmapcluster

Comment: The accepted answer here is the same code as the accepted answer in the duplicate (by the same person).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure completely understand, but it appears you are trying to re-index each axis of the array based on sorts of the dendrogram indicies.  I guess that assumes there is some comparative logic in each branch delineation.  If this is the case then would this work(?):

```
>>> x_idxs = [(0,1,0,0),(0,1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1),(1,1,1,1),(0,0,0,0)]
>>> y_idxs = [(1,1),(0,1),(1,0),(0,0)]
>>> a = np.random.random((len(x_idxs),len(y_idxs)))
>>> x_idxs2, xi = zip(*sorted(zip(x_idxs,range(len(x_idxs)))))
>>> y_idxs2, yi = zip(*sorted(zip(y_idxs,range(len(y_idxs)))))
>>> a2 = a[xi,:][:,yi]
```

`x_idxs` and `y_idxs` are the dendrogram indicies.  `a` is the unsorted matrix.  `xi` and `yi` are your new row/column array indicies.  `a2` is the sorted matrix while `x_idxs2` and `y_idxs2` are the new, sorted dendrogram indicies.  This assumes that when the dendrogram was created that a `0` branch column/row is always comparatively larger/smaller than a `1` branch.

If your y_idxs and x_idxs are not lists but are numpy arrays, then you could use `np.argsort` in a similar manner.

Comment: what exactly does * in "zip(*sorted..." do?

Comment: whenever I see `zip(*`, I think "transpose".
See here for the use of `*` for unpacking: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: and some more discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very late to the game, but I made a plotting object based on the code from the post on this page. It's registered on pip, so to install you just have to call

```
pip install pydendroheatmap
```

check out the project's github page here : https://github.com/themantalope/pydendroheatmap