# hierarchical clustering with gene expression matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, matplotlib, scipy

how can I do a hierarchical clustering (in this case for gene expression data) in Python in a way that shows the matrix of gene expression values along with the dendrogram?  What I mean is like the example here:

http://www.mathworks.cn/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ug/a1060813239b1.html

shown after bullet point 6 (Figure 1), where the dendrogram is plotted to the left of the gene expression matrix, where the rows have been reordered to reflect the clustering.

How can I do this in Python using numpy/scipy or other tools? Also, is it computationally practical to do this with a matrix of about 11,000 genes, using euclidean distance as a metric?

EDIT: Many have suggested clustering packages, but I am still unsure how to plot the kind of image I linked to above in Python. How can I overlay a dendrogram alongside a heatmap matrix, using Matplotlib for example?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Many clustering methods including `scipy.cluster` start by sorting all pairwise distances,
~ 60 million in your case, not too big.
How long does the following take for you ?

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hier
import pylab as pl

def fcluster( pts, ncluster, method="average", criterion="maxclust" ):
    """ -> (pts, Y pdist, Z linkage, T fcluster, clusterlists)   
        ncluster = n1 + n2 + ... (including n1 singletons)
        av cluster size = len(pts) / ncluster
    """
    pts = np.asarray(pts)
    Y = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist( pts )  # ~ N^2 / 2
    Z = hier.linkage( Y, method )  # N-1                         
    T = hier.fcluster( Z, ncluster, criterion=criterion )
        # clusters = clusterlists(T)
    return (pts, Y, Z, T)

hier.dendrogram( Z )
```

How to permute the matrix and plot nicely was asked
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455761/reordering-matrix-elements-to-reflect-column-and-row-clustering-in-naiive-python)
in So in March, with a partial answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with scipy's [cluster.hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html) module. The commands are actually even very similar. However, you will have to use `correlation` instead of `corr` as a parameter to `pdist` and rather than `cluster` the name of the function scipy's cluster module is `fcluster`. Also, for the dendrogram, the function is `dendrogram` in scipy as opposed to `clustergram` in Matlab.

You  can definitely use a euclidean metric (think it is the default for `pdist`). I think that it should be feasible to do this with 11,000 genes because that will be 11000*(11000-1)/2 = 60494500 (11000 choose 2) distances to be computed. That's a large number, but certainly feasible I would think.

Comment: Are there tools for plotting the resulting dendrogram in scipy?

Comment: You'll also want the `matplotlib` module. It might help to look at this document: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~turnbull/cs67/s09/labs/lab05.pdf It uses the scipy-cluster package (hcluster) which I'm pretty certain is what has been put in the scipy.cluster.hierarchy module.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of people have made some decent progress in creating a prototype module for hierarchical clustering and heatmap visualization using scipy and matplotlib:

[How to get flat clustering corresponding to color clusters in the dendrogram created by scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664826/how-to-get-flat-clustering-corresponding-to-color-clusters-in-the-dendrogram-cre)

I've been adapting this code to make a full-fledged hierarchical clustering module that I can integrate into one of my transcriptome analysis packages. I'm pretty happy with the final product which will produce a heatmap using various clustering metrics and methods and coloring gradients. The code and an example output is shown here:

http://altanalyze.blogspot.com/2012/06/hierarchical-clustering-heatmaps-in.html