# How to get flat clustering corresponding to color clusters in the dendrogram created by scipy

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, scipy, hierarchical, hierarchical-clustering

Using the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455761/reordering-matrix-elements-to-reflect-column-and-row-clustering-in-naiive-python/3017704#3017704), I created a nice hierarchical clustering:

[image: scipy dendrogram]

Let's say the the dendrogram on the left was created by doing something like

```
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='average') # D is a distance matrix
cutoff = 0.5*max(Y[:,2])
Z = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='right', color_threshold=cutoff)
```

Now **how do I get the indices of the members of each of the colored clusters?**  To simplify this situation, ignore the clustering on the top, and focus only on the dendrogram on the left of the matrix.

This information should be stored in the dendrogram `Z` stored variable.  There is a function that should do just what I want called `fcluster` (see documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster)). However I cannot see where I can give fcluster the same `cutoff` as I specified in the creation of the dendrogram.  It seems that the threshold variable in `fcluster`, `t` has to be in terms of various obscure measurements (`inconsistent`, `distance`, `maxclust`, `monocrit`).  Any ideas?

Comment: Please note that if your `D` is a symmetric distance matrix, then you are wrong. Instead, the input of `linkage()` should be a n-choose-2 array as @Steve has done.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Let's try this:

```
import scipy
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
X = scipy.randn(100, 2)     # 100 2-dimensional observations
d = sch.distance.pdist(X)   # vector of (100 choose 2) pairwise distances
L = sch.linkage(d, method='complete')
ind = sch.fcluster(L, 0.5*d.max(), 'distance')
```

`ind` will give you cluster indices for each of the 100 input observations. `ind` depends on what `method` you used in `linkage`. Try `method=single`, `complete`, and `average`. Then note how `ind` differs.

Example:

```
In [59]: L = sch.linkage(d, method='complete')

In [60]: sch.fcluster(L, 0.5*d.max(), 'distance')
Out[60]: 
array([5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5,
       2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4,
       2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5,
       2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5,
       4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2])

In [61]: L = sch.linkage(d, method='single')

In [62]: sch.fcluster(L, 0.5*d.max(), 'distance')
Out[62]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

`scipy.cluster.hierarchy` sure is confusing. In your link, I don't even recognize my own code!

Comment: That's right.  The main problem here is that there are several distance metrics taken by the fcluster function.  One of them happens to be called 'distance'.  As far as I can tell, the scipy documentation does not mention that the dendrogram function which draws and colors the dendrograms also uses the 'distance' metric for its distance calculation.  That caused by confusion.  Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @Steve. I am trying to adapt the code into the test data with random set of 100 2d vectors but i am getting this error:   File "mycluster.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "mycluster.py", line 58, in main
    cluster(data)
  File "mycluster.py", line 46, in cluster
    cmap=pylab.cm.YlGnBu)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7704, in matshow
    nr, nc = Z.shape
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Also what does the ind represents. what are all these 1s?

Comment: `ind` is the cluster index for each observation. In this example, there are 100 observations, hence 100 cluster indices, one for each observation. Regarding your first question, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote some code to decondense the linkage matrix. It returns a dictionary containing the indexes of `labels` that are grouped by each agglomeration step. I've only tried it out on the results of the `complete` linkage clusters. The keys of the dict start at `len(labels)+1` because initially, each label is treated as its own cluster. This may answer your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage

np.random.seed(123)
labels = ['ID_0','ID_1','ID_2','ID_3','ID_4']

X = np.corrcoef(np.random.random_sample([5,3])*10)
row_clusters = linkage(x_corr, method='complete')    

def extract_levels(row_clusters, labels):
    clusters = {}
    for row in xrange(row_clusters.shape[0]):
        cluster_n = row + len(labels)
        # which clusters / labels are present in this row
        glob1, glob2 = row_clusters[row, 0], row_clusters[row, 1]

        # if this is a cluster, pull the cluster
        this_clust = []
        for glob in [glob1, glob2]:
            if glob > (len(labels)-1):
                this_clust += clusters[glob]
            # if it isn't, add the label to this cluster
            else:
                this_clust.append(glob)

        clusters[cluster_n] = this_clust
    return clusters
```

Returns:

```
{5: [0.0, 2.0],
 6: [3.0, 4.0],
 7: [1.0, 0.0, 2.0],
 8: [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late to the game, but I made a plotting object based on the code from the post [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578175-hierarchical-clustering-heatmap-python/). It's registered on pip, so to install you just have to call

```
pip install pydendroheatmap
```

check out the project's github page here : https://github.com/themantalope/pydendroheatmap

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [`cut_tree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree.html), it has a height parameter that should give you what you want for ultrametrics.