# Get the clusters from agglomerative for a given truncation

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

From the example of scikit-learn using scipy, (only changing the truncate_mode from 'level' to 'lastp'),

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering


def plot_dendrogram(model, **kwargs):
    # Create linkage matrix and then plot the dendrogram

    # create the counts of samples under each node
    counts = np.zeros(model.children_.shape[0])
    n_samples = len(model.labels_)
    for i, merge in enumerate(model.children_):
        current_count = 0
        for child_idx in merge:
            if child_idx < n_samples:
                current_count += 1  # leaf node
            else:
                current_count += counts[child_idx - n_samples]
        counts[i] = current_count

    linkage_matrix = np.column_stack(
        [model.children_, model.distances_, counts]
    ).astype(float)

    # Plot the corresponding dendrogram
    dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs)


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data

# setting distance_threshold=0 ensures we compute the full tree.
model = AgglomerativeClustering(distance_threshold=0, n_clusters=None)

model = model.fit(X)
plt.title("Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram")
# plot the top three levels of the dendrogram
plot_dendrogram(model, truncate_mode="lastp", p=10)
plt.xlabel("Number of points in node (or index of point if no parenthesis).")
plt.show()
```

I get,

[image: dendogram example]

Now, how can I get the elements that belong to each of the clusters for that specific truncation?
I would like to know the indices of 21, 17, 12 etc elements that constitute each of those clusters.

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034792/print-all-clusters-and-samples-at-each-step-of-hierarchical-clustering-in-python) might help