# multidimensional hierarchical clustering - python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, cluster-analysis

is there something out there that does multidimensional hierarchical clustering?

I have looked in these places:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram

but with no success so far

meaning: finding groups same way that was done with 2 dimensions, but with multiple dimensions

some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
set_of_values = pd.DataFrame(
    [np.random.rand(10),
     np.random.rand(10),
     np.random.rand(10),
     np.random.rand(10),
     np.random.rand(10),],
     index=['temp differential', 'power differential', 'cost', 'time','output'],
    columns=range(10)).transpose()
print(set_of_values)
```

I'd like to find all the clusters for ('temp differential', 'power differential', 'cost', 'time','output'). not graphically as it is an hyperplane. ideally with an output like [all the groups]:

```
GROUP #1: (a,b,c,d,e), (a',b',c',d',e'), ... , (a'',b'',c'',d'',e'') 
...
GROUP #n: ('a,'b,'c,'d,'e), ('a,'b,'c,'d,'e), ... , (''a,''b,''c,''d,''e)
```

given a threshold on the progressive 'clustering'. is it doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick example. Here, this is clustering 4 random variables with hierarchical clustering:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col" + str(num): np.random.randn(50) for num in range(1,5)})
sns.clustermap(df)
```

[image]

If you are concerned with understanding the dendrogram linkages and thresholding to get clusters, the seaborn tool uses scipy and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664826/how-to-get-flat-clustering-corresponding-to-color-clusters-in-the-dendrogram-cre) would be helpful.

If you want to visualize this in space, I'd recommend using Principal Component Analysis and plotting PC1 vs PC2 http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html

Comment: That was what Iwas looking for