# Which cluster does X[i] belong to?

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I have a large data matrix `X` and I use SciPy implementation of Ward's hierarchical clustering like so:

```
Z = ward(X.todense())
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
dn = dendrogram(Z)
```

I now wish to see which classes `X[i]` belongs to. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `linkage` matrix `Z` you can get the clusters with `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster`.

First, I assume you want the same clusters as the colors of `dendrogram`. From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram) we can see that the `color_threshold` is set to `0.7*max(Z[:,2])` if nothing else is specified. So that is what we will use.

For example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10)
Z = linkage(X, method='ward')
thresh = 0.7*max(Z[:,2])
fcluster(Z, thresh, criterion='distance')
```

See also [How to get flat clustering corresponding to color clusters in the dendrogram created by scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664826/how-to-get-flat-clustering-corresponding-to-color-clusters-in-the-dendrogram-cre)