# Sorting list according to corresponding values from a parallel list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of strings like this:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,   0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1 ]
```

What is the shortest way of sorting X using values from Y to get the following output?

```
["a", "d", "h", "b", "c", "e", "i", "f", "g"]
```

The order of the elements having the same "key" does not matter. I can resort to the use of `for` constructs but I am curious if there is a shorter way. Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer of riza might be useful when plotting data, since zip(*sorted(zip(X, Y), key=lambda pair: pair[0])) returns both the sorted X and Y sorted with values of X.

Comment: [More general case (sort list Y by any key instead of the default order)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64150122/5267751)

Comment: Though it might not be obvious, this is exactly equivalent to **sorting Y**, and rearranging X in the same way that Y was sorted. I had both of these questions in my saves for quite some time - and anguished over them, because something seemed not quite right - until today when I realized the duplication (after working the other one to make it clearer and improve the title).

Answer (score 843, accepted):

**Shortest Code**

```
[x for _, x in sorted(zip(Y, X))]
```

**Example:**

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,    0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1]

Z = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(Y,X))]
print(Z)  # ["a", "d", "h", "b", "c", "e", "i", "f", "g"]
```

---

**Generally Speaking**

```
[x for _, x in sorted(zip(Y, X), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]
```

**Explained:**

1. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two `list`s.
2. create a new, sorted `list` based on the `zip` using [`sorted()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted).
3. using a list comprehension *extract* the first elements of each pair from the sorted, zipped `list`.

*For more information on how to set\use the `key` parameter as well as the `sorted` function in general, take a look at [this](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/).*

---

Comment: This is correct, but I'll add the note that if you're trying to sort multiple arrays by the same array, this won't neccessarily work as expected, since the key that is being used to sort is (y,x), not just y. You should instead use [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(Y,X), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]

Comment: good solution! But it should be: The list is ordered regarding the first element of the pairs, and the comprehension extracts the 'second' element of the pairs.

Comment: This solution is poor when it comes to storage. An in-place sort is preferred whenever possible.

Comment: @Hatefiend interesting, could you point to a reference on how to achieve that?

Comment: @RichieV I recommend using Quicksort or an in-place merge sort implementation. Once you have that, define your own comparison function which compares values based on the indexes of list `Y`. The end result should be list `Y` being untouched and list `X` being changed into the expected solution without ever having to create a temp list.

Comment: Z = [e[1] for e in sorted(zip(Y,X))] is just as good, and, at least for me, it is easier to understand.

Comment: The "Shortest Code" method does not work if list X contains objects. The "general speaking" method should be provided first. For reference, a shorter general method; ` Z = sorted(X, key=lambda x: Y[X.index(x)])`

Comment: Small rant: how is it possible that there is not some built in function that just takes two lists, one to be sorted and the other as the key. If you can call sorted() on a generic list and it is able to figure out how to sort it regardless the data type of the elements, then why isn't there some syntax that is my_list = sorted(my_list, some_other_list)? IMHO all these solutions, although elegant and pythonic, feel like a workaround around a problem that should not be there in the first place.

Answer (score 146):

Zip the two lists together, sort it, then take the parts you want:

```
>>> yx = zip(Y, X)
>>> yx
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (0, 'd'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'f'), (2, 'g'), (0, 'h'), (1, 'i')]
>>> yx.sort()
>>> yx
[(0, 'a'), (0, 'd'), (0, 'h'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'e'), (1, 'i'), (2, 'f'), (2, 'g')]
>>> x_sorted = [x for y, x in yx]
>>> x_sorted
['a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g']
```

Combine these together to get:

```
[x for y, x in sorted(zip(Y, X))]
```

Comment: This is fine if `X` is a list of `str`, but be careful if there is a possibility that `<` is not defined for some pairs of items in `X`, eg - if some of them were `None`

Comment: When we try to use sort over a zip object, `AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'sort'` is what I am getting as of now.

Comment: You are using Python 3.  In Python 2, zip produced a list.  Now it produces an iterable object.  `sorted(zip(...))` should still work, or:  `them = list(zip(...)); them.sort()`

Answer (score 136):

Also, if you don't mind using numpy arrays (or in fact already are dealing with numpy arrays...), here is another nice solution:

```
people = ['Jim', 'Pam', 'Micheal', 'Dwight']
ages = [27, 25, 4, 9]

import numpy
people = numpy.array(people)
ages = numpy.array(ages)
inds = ages.argsort()
sortedPeople = people[inds]
```

I found it here:
http://scienceoss.com/sort-one-list-by-another-list/

Comment: For bigger arrays / vectors, this solution with numpy is beneficial!

Comment: If they are already numpy arrays, then it's simply `sortedArray1= array1[array2.argsort()]`.  And this also makes it easy to sort multiple lists by a particular column of a 2D array: e.g. `sortedArray1= array1[array2[:,2].argsort()]` to sort array1 (which may have multiple columns) by the values in the third column of array2.

Comment: @Tom Jim + Pam = Jam!

Answer (score 49):

The most obvious solution to me is to use the `key` keyword arg.

```
>>> X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
>>> Y = [ 0,   1,   1,    0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1]
>>> keydict = dict(zip(X, Y))
>>> X.sort(key=keydict.get)
>>> X
['a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g']
```

Note that you can shorten this to a one-liner if you care to:

```
>>> X.sort(key=dict(zip(X, Y)).get)
```

As Wenmin Mu and Jack Peng have pointed out, this assumes that the values in `X` are all distinct. That's easily managed with an index list:

```
>>> Z = ["A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
>>> Z_index = list(range(len(Z)))
>>> Z_index.sort(key=keydict.get)
>>> Z = [Z[i] for i in Z_index]
>>> Z
['A', 'C', 'H', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'I', 'F', 'G']
```

Since the decorate-sort-undecorate approach described by [Whatang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618543/577088) is a little simpler and works in all cases, it's probably better most of the time. (This is a very old answer!)

Comment: Does this require that the values in X are unqiue?

Answer (score 40):

[`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sort_together) has a tool for sorting iterables in parallel:

**Given**

```
from more_itertools import sort_together


X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,    0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1]
```

**Demo**

```
sort_together([Y, X])[1]
# ('a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g')
```

Comment: I like this because I can do multiple lists with one index ```sort_together([Index,X,Y,Z])```

Comment: Oh, ignore, I can do sorted(zip(Index,X,Y,Z)) too.

Answer (score 27):

I actually came here looking to sort a list by a list where the values matched.

```
list_a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
list_b = ['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
sorted(list_b, key=lambda x: list_a.index(x))
# ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. `index` will perform an _O(N)_ search  on `list_a` resulting in an `O(N² log N)` sort.

Comment: @Richard: the keys are computed once before sorting; so the complexity is actually O(N^2).

Comment: @Stef true, but still a bad idea.

Answer (score 18):

Another alternative, combining several of the answers.

```
zip(*sorted(zip(Y,X)))[1]
```

In order to work for python3:

```
list(zip(*sorted(zip(B,A))))[1]
```

Comment: original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620187

Answer (score 16):

I like having a list of sorted indices. That way, I can sort any list in the same order as the source list. Once you have a list of sorted indices, a simple list comprehension will do the trick:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,    0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1]

sorted_y_idx_list = sorted(range(len(Y)),key=lambda x:Y[x])
Xs = [X[i] for i in sorted_y_idx_list ]

print( "Xs:", Xs )
# prints: Xs: ["a", "d", "h", "b", "c", "e", "i", "f", "g"]
```

Note that the sorted index list can also be gotten using `numpy.argsort()`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to sort multiple lists at once by one sorted index list?

Something like this?

`X1= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
X2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]

X1s, X2s = [X1[i], X2[i] for i in sorted_y_idx_list ]`

Answer (score 8):

zip, sort by the second column, return the first column.

```
zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))[0]
```

Comment: Note: the key=operator.itemgetter(1) solves the duplicate issue

Comment: zip is not subscriptable... you must actually use `list(zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))[0]`

Comment: @Keith what duplicate issue?

Comment: If there is more than one matching it gets the first

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19339

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but some of the answers I see posted don't actually work because `zip` is not scriptable. Other answers didn't bother to `import operator` and provide more info about this module and its benefits here.

There are at least two good idioms for this problem. Starting with the example input you provided:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,   0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1 ]
```

#### Using the "[Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-decorate-sort-undecorate)" idiom

This is also known as the [Schwartzian_transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) after [R. Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randal_L._Schwartz) who popularized this pattern in Perl in the 90s:

```
# Zip (decorate), sort and unzip (undecorate).
# Converting to list to script the output and extract X
list(zip(*(sorted(zip(Y,X)))))[1]                                                                                                                       
# Results in: ('a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g')
```

Note that in this case `Y` and `X` are sorted and compared lexicographically. That is, the first items (from `Y`) are compared; and if they are the same then the second items (from `X`) are compared, and so on. This can create [unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) outputs unless you include the original list indices for the lexicographic ordering to keep duplicates in their original order.

#### Using the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

This gives you more direct control over how to sort the input, so you can get [sorting stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) by simply stating the specific key to sort by. See more examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#operator-module-functions).

```
import operator    

# Sort by Y (1) and extract X [0]
list(zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))[0]                                                                                                 
# Results in: ('a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g')
```

Comment: I think in most cases I would just use `lambda x: x[1]` instead of `operator.itemgetter(1)`, since it easier to understand and doesn't require an additional package. Is there an advantage to using `operator.itemgetter`?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `pandas Series`, using the primary list as `data` and the other list as `index`, and then just sort by the index:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(data=X,index=Y).sort_index().tolist()
```

output:

```
['a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is Whatangs answer if you want to get both sorted lists (python3).

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,    0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1]

Zx, Zy = zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in sorted(zip(Y, X))])

print(list(Zx))  # [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
print(list(Zy))  # ['a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g']
```

Just remember Zx and Zy are tuples.
I am also wandering if there is a better way to do that.

**Warning:** If you run it with empty lists it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a more general function, that sorts more than two lists based on another one, inspired by @Whatang's answer.

```
def parallel_sort(*lists):
    """
    Sorts the given lists, based on the first one.
    :param lists: lists to be sorted

    :return: a tuple containing the sorted lists
    """

    # Create the initially empty lists to later store the sorted items
    sorted_lists = tuple([] for _ in range(len(lists)))

    # Unpack the lists, sort them, zip them and iterate over them
    for t in sorted(zip(*lists)):
        # list items are now sorted based on the first list
        for i, item in enumerate(t):    # for each item...
            sorted_lists[i].append(item)  # ...store it in the appropriate list

    return sorted_lists
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,   0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1 ]
```

You can do so in one line:

```
X, Y = zip(*sorted(zip(Y, X)))
```

Comment: The previous answer is sorting `B` using values from `A`. It's correct but misleading. I fixed it, thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the solutions above are complicated and I think they will not work if the lists are of different lengths or do not contain the exact same items. The solution below is simple and does not require any imports.

```
list1 = ['B', 'A', 'C']  # Required sort order
list2 = ['C', 'B']       # Items to be sorted according to list1

result = list1
for item in list1:
    if item not in list2: result.remove(item)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['B', 'C']
```

- Note: Any item not in list1 will be ignored since the algorithm will not know what's the sort order to use.

Comment: You posted your solution two times. Maybe you can delete one of them. In addition, the proposed solution won't work for the initial question as the lists X and Y contain different entries.

Comment: That's right but the solutions use completely different methods which could be used for different applications. If you already have a df...why converting it to a list, process it, then convert to df again? you can leverage that solution directly in your existing df. The second one is easier and faster if you're not using Pandas in your program. As for won't work..that's right because he posted the wrong question in the title when he talked about lists. His title should have been 'How to sort a dictionary?'.  People will search this post looking to sort lists not dictionaries. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick one-liner.

```
list_a = [5,4,3,2,1]
list_b = [1,1.5,1.75,2,3,3.5,3.75,4,5]
```

Say you want list a to match list b.

```
orderedList =  sorted(list_a, key=lambda x: list_b.index(x))
```

This is helpful when needing to order a smaller list to values in larger. Assuming that the larger list contains all values in the smaller list, it can be done.

Comment: This does not solve the OP’s question.  Did you try it with the sample lists `X` and `Y`?

Comment: This is a bad idea. `index` will perform an _O(N)_ search  on `list_b` resulting in an `O(N² log N)` sort.

Answer (score 1):

This function should work for arrays.

```
def sortBoth(x,y,reverse=False):
    '''
    Sort both x and y, according to x. 
    '''
    xy_sorted=array(sorted(zip(x,y),reverse=reverse)).T
    return xy_sorted[0],xy_sorted[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the solutions above will not work if the 2 lists are of different sizes or contain different items. The solution below is simple and should fix those issues:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ['B', 'A', 'C']  # Required sort order
list2 = ['C', 'A']       # Items to be sorted according to list1

result = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(list1), pd.DataFrame(list2))
print(list(result[0]))
```

output:

```
['A', 'C']
```

- Note: Any item not in list1 will be ignored since the algorithm will not know what's the sort order to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
list2 = [0,1,1,0,1,2,2,0,1]

output=[]
cur_loclist = []
```

To get unique values present in `list2`

```
list_set = set(list2)
```

To find the loc of the index in `list2`

```
list_str = ''.join(str(s) for s in list2)
```

Location of index in `list2` is tracked using `cur_loclist`

[0, 3, 7, 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6]

```
for i in list_set:
cur_loc = list_str.find(str(i))

while cur_loc >= 0:
    cur_loclist.append(cur_loc)
    cur_loc = list_str.find(str(i),cur_loc+1)

print(cur_loclist)

for i in range(0,len(cur_loclist)):
output.append(list1[cur_loclist[i]])
print(output)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that the title of the original question is not accurate. If you have 2 lists of identical number of items and where every item in list 1 is related to list 2 in the same order (e.g a = 0 , b = 1, etc.) then the question should be 'How to sort a dictionary?', not 'How to sorting list based on values from another list?'. The solution below is the most efficient in this case:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ 0,   1,   1,   0,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1 ]

dict1 = dict(zip(X,Y))
result = sorted(dict1, key=dict1.get)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'd', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f', 'g']
```