# Given parallel lists, how can I sort one while permuting (rearranging) the other in the same way?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Suppose I have:

```
list1 = [3, 2, 4, 1, 1]
list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']
```

Calling `list1.sort()` will sort it, resulting in `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. However, can I get `list2` to be rearranged in sync with that, to get a result like this?

```
list1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = ['one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

---

<sub>Sometimes, people [phrase the problem differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515): given two lists, they would like to use one to determine the sort order for the other - i.e., sort `list2` in the order described by the corresponding values in `list1`. The trick is that this is equivalent to **sorting the "key" values** (`list1`), and then rearranging `list2` in the same way. In other words, exactly what is described here. Some answers for the other question, though, discard the "sorted keys" afterwards.</sub>

<sub>See also: [How can I sort a list, according to where its elements appear in another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016827) - this is another common way that people want to sort one list "based on" another. Before attempting to close duplicate questions, take special care to check exactly what the OP wants. A key clue: do the lists need to be the same length?</sub>

Comment: I should point out that your variables in list2 don't point to the ints in list1. E.g. if change a value such as list1[0]=9 and look at list2, list2[0] will still be 3. With integers in python, it doesn't use the reference/pointer, it copies the value. You would have been better off going list2 = list1[:]

Answer (score 382, accepted):

One classic approach to this problem is to use the "decorate, sort, undecorate" idiom, which is especially simple using python's built-in `zip` function:

```
>>> list1 = [3,2,4,1, 1]
>>> list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']
>>> list1, list2 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
>>> list1
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> list2 
('one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four')
```

These of course are no longer lists, but that's easily remedied, if it matters:

```
>>> list1, list2 = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2))))
>>> list1
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2
['one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

It's worth noting that the above may sacrifice speed for terseness; the in-place version, which takes up 3 lines, is a tad faster on my machine for small lists:

```
>>> %timeit zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.3 us per loop
>>> %timeit tups = zip(list1, list2); tups.sort(); zip(*tups)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.84 us per loop
```

On the other hand, for larger lists, the one-line version could be faster:

```
>>> %timeit zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.09 ms per loop
>>> %timeit tups = zip(list1, list2); tups.sort(); zip(*tups)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.51 ms per loop
```

As Quantum7 points out, [JSF's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764390/577088) is a bit faster still, but it will probably only ever be a little bit faster, because Python uses the [very same DSU idiom internally](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e4c32152b25b/Objects/listobject.c#l1863) for all key-based sorts. It's just happening a little closer to the bare metal. (This shows just how well optimized the `zip` routines are!)

I think the `zip`-based approach is more flexible and is a little more readable, so I prefer it.

---

Note that when elements of `list1` are equal, this approach will end up comparing elements of `list2`. If elements of `list2` don't support comparison, or don't produce a boolean when compared (for example, if `list2` is a list of NumPy arrays), this will fail, and if elements of `list2` are very expensive to compare, it might be better to avoid comparison anyway.

In that case, you can sort indices as suggested in jfs's answer, or you can give the sort a key function that avoids comparing elements of `list2`:

```
result1, result2 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Also, the use of `zip(*...)` as a transpose fails when the input is empty. If your inputs might be empty, you will have to handle that case separately.

Comment: what does the asterisk in the third line represent?

Comment: To elaborate on the above, the `*` operator does [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists),

Comment: The sorted index/map paradigm suggested by J.F. Sebastian is about 10% faster than either zip solution for me (using lists of 10000 random ints):

%timeit index = range(len(l1)); index.sort(key=l1.__getitem__); map(l1.__getitem__, index); map(l2.__getitem__, index)

100 loops, best of 3: 8.04 ms per loop (vs 9.17 ms, 9.07 ms for senderle's timits)

Comment: The first and second zip in list1, list2 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2))) do such different things. The * makes all the difference.

Comment: @ashu, in a sense, yes! But in another sense, they're hardly different at all. `zip(*x)` has the interesting property that it is its own inverse:  `l = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]; list(zip(*zip(*l))) == l` returns `True`. It's effectively a transposition operator. `zip()` on its own is just the same operator, but assumes that you have unpacked the input sequence manually.

Comment: Yes. I wonder if the subtlety was only something I stumbled at and is obvious to everyone, or is indeed a little involved. Noticing this property of zip to make this entire operation work in one line is non trivial at the very least.

Comment: @senderie You can get rid of the tuple comprehension in your second code paragraph and use `list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2))))`.

Comment: @Guimoute, ah well it's a matter of opinion I guess—but I generally find generator expressions and list comprehensions more readable than `map`.

Comment: which is the one line version? I don't get it... what is the version to get a list and so it would be fast on big sets?

Answer (score 52):

You can sort indexes using values as keys:

```
indexes = range(len(list1))
indexes.sort(key=list1.__getitem__)

# Or on Python 3, where range does not return a list
indexes = sorted(range(len(list1)), key=list1.__getitem__)
```

To get sorted lists given sorted indexes:

```
sorted_list1 = map(list1.__getitem__, indexes)
sorted_list2 = map(list2.__getitem__, indexes)

# Python 3 version, converting map iterator to true list
sorted_list1 = list(map(list1.__getitem__, indexes))
sorted_list2 = list(map(list2.__getitem__, indexes))
```

In your case you shouldn't have `list1`, `list2` but rather a single list of pairs:

```
data = [(3, 'three'), (2, 'two'), (4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (1, 'one2')]
```

It is easy to create; it is easy to sort in Python:

```
data.sort() # sort using a pair as a key
```

Sort by the first value only:

```
data.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[0])
```

Comment: The cool thing about this is that I can keep indexes around and sort other stuff later, in case list1 is an important coordinate that affects several other arrays.

Comment: indexes = list(range(len(list1))) for python 3

Comment: @DonQuiKong you also need to `list() `around `map()` if you'd like to use this code in Python 3.

Comment: Or, instead of `sorted_list1 = list(map(list1.__getitem__, indexes))` one could do `sorted_list1 = [list1[i] for i in indexes]`.

Comment: You know it is obvious once you see it but my brain certainly wasn't coming up with this.

Comment: @DonQuiKong: I edited in a similar version of that. Since you need to both convert to `list` and `sort`, the Python 3 version of creating `indexes` can be one-lined with zero overhead (where on Python 2, using `sorted` on the result of `range` would make an unnecessary temporary `list`).

Answer (score 33):

I have used the answer given by senderle for a long time until I discovered `np.argsort`.
Here is how it works.

```
# idx works on np.array and not lists.
list1 = np.array([3,2,4,1])
list2 = np.array(["three","two","four","one"])
idx   = np.argsort(list1)

list1 = np.array(list1)[idx]
list2 = np.array(list2)[idx]
```

I find this solution more intuitive, and it works really well. The perfomance:

```
def sorting(l1, l2):
    # l1 and l2 has to be numpy arrays
    idx = np.argsort(l1)
    return l1[idx], l2[idx]

# list1 and list2 are np.arrays here...
%timeit sorting(list1, list2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.53 us per loop

# This works best when the lists are NOT np.array
%timeit zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.41 us per loop

# 0.01us better for np.array (I think this is negligible)
%timeit tups = zip(list1, list2); tups.sort(); zip(*tups)
100000 loops, best for 3 loops: 1.96 us per loop
```

Even though `np.argsort` isn't the fastest one, I find it easier to use.

Comment: I get an error running your example: `TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index` (Python 2.7.6, numpy 1.8.2). To fix it, list1 and list2 must be declared as numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't this what I write in the comment in the function? Anyway, I think it's silly that `np.argsort` don't try to convert to a `np.array` internally.

Comment: I was referring to the first code snippet since it doesn't run as written :)

Comment: I corrected it by converting the lists when they are assigned to numpy arrays. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Now they're converted to Numpy arrays twice ;)

Comment: I call it bullet proof, you may call it something else ;)
Yes, it is only needed to make the lists numpy arrays once (in the beginning preferrably, then you don't worry about it anymore).

Answer (score 16):

This can be done using what Perl programmers call the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), also known as the decorate-sort-undecorate idiom. The built-in Python sorting is stable, so the two `1`s don't cause a problem.

```
>>> l1 = [3, 2, 4, 1, 1]
>>> l2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'second one']
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(l1, l2)))
[(1, 1, 2, 3, 4), ('one', 'second one', 'two', 'three', 'four')]
```

Comment: However, if you find you need to do this, you should strongly re-consider having the two "parallel" lists of data, as opposed to keeping a list of 2-tuples (pairs)... or perhaps even actually creating a class.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `zip()` and `sort()` functions to accomplish this:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
>>> list1 = [3,2,4,1,1]
>>> list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']
>>> zipped = zip(list1, list2)
>>> zipped.sort()
>>> slist1 = [i for (i, s) in zipped]
>>> slist1
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> slist2 = [s for (i, s) in zipped]
>>> slist2
['one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is anyone else getting the error "AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'sort'"? I'm wondering if this response works for earlier versions of Python but not current ones.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to track where each index goes to by sorting the identity [0,1,2,..n]

This works for any number of lists.

Then move each item to its position. Using splices is best.

```
list1 = [3,2,4,1, 1]
list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']

index = list(range(len(list1)))
print(index)
'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]'

index.sort(key = list1.__getitem__)
print(index)
'[3, 4, 1, 0, 2]'

list1[:] = [list1[i] for i in index]
list2[:] = [list2[i] for i in index]

print(list1)
print(list2)
'[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]'
"['one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four']"
```

Note we could have iterated the lists without even sorting them:

```
list1_iter = (list1[i] for i in index)
```

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
list1 = [3,2,4,1, 1]
list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']

sortedRes = sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: x[0]) # use 0 or 1 depending on what you want to sort
>>> [(1, 'one'), (1, 'one2'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using numpy you can use `np.argsort` to get the sorted indices and apply those indices to the list. This works for any number of list that you would want to sort.

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([4,3,1,32,21])
arr2 = arr1 * 10
sorted_idxs = np.argsort(arr1)

print(sorted_idxs)
>>> array([2, 1, 0, 4, 3])

print(arr1[sorted_idxs])
>>> array([ 1,  3,  4, 21, 32])

print(arr2[sorted_idxs])
>>> array([ 10,  30,  40, 210, 320])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the key argument in sorted() method unless you have two same values in list2.

The code is given below:

```
sorted(list2, key = lambda x: list1[list2.index(x)])
```

It sorts list2 according to corresponding values in list1, but make sure that while using this, no two values in list2 evaluate to be equal because list.index() function give the first value

Comment: sorted is somewhat slow in some condition though it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach to retaining the order of a string list when sorting against another list is as follows:**

```
list1 = [3,2,4,1, 1]
list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']

# sort on list1 while retaining order of string list
sorted_list1 = [y for _,y in sorted(zip(list1,list2),key=lambda x: x[0])]
sorted_list2 = sorted(list1)

print(sorted_list1)
print(sorted_list2)
```

**output**

```
['one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four']
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand open [jfs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764390/10476976), which worked great for my problem: **sorting two lists by a third, decorated list**:

We can create our decorated list in any way, but in this case we will create it from the elements of one of the two original lists, that we want to sort:

```
# say we have the following list and we want to sort both by the algorithms name 
# (if we were to sort by the string_list, it would sort by the numerical 
# value in the strings)
string_list = ["0.123 Algo. XYZ", "0.345 Algo. BCD", "0.987 Algo. ABC"]
dict_list = [{"dict_xyz": "XYZ"}, {"dict_bcd": "BCD"}, {"dict_abc": "ABC"}]

# thus we need to create the decorator list, which we can now use to sort
decorated = [text[6:] for text in string_list]  
# decorated list to sort
>>> decorated
['Algo. XYZ', 'Algo. BCD', 'Algo. ABC']
```

Now we can apply [jfs's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764390/10476976) to sort our two lists by the third

```
# create and sort the list of indices
sorted_indices = list(range(len(string_list)))
sorted_indices.sort(key=decorated.__getitem__)

# map sorted indices to the two, original lists
sorted_stringList = list(map(string_list.__getitem__, sorted_indices))
sorted_dictList = list(map(dict_list.__getitem__, sorted_indices))

# output
>>> sorted_stringList
['0.987 Algo. ABC', '0.345 Algo. BCD', '0.123 Algo. XYZ']
>>> sorted_dictList
[{'dict_abc': 'ABC'}, {'dict_bcd': 'BCD'}, {'dict_xyz': 'XYZ'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a solution if you need to sort more than 2 lists in sync:

```
def SortAndSyncList_Multi(ListToSort, *ListsToSync):
    y = sorted(zip(ListToSort, zip(*ListsToSync)))
    w = [n for n in zip(*y)]
    return list(w[0]), tuple(list(a) for a in zip(*w[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@pylang's answer to the duplicate question I just closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514542/523612), the necessary algorithm is implemented in the popular third-party library `more_itertools`, as [sort_together](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sort_together).

Thus:

```
from more_itertools import sort_together

list1 = [3, 2, 4, 1, 1]
list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']

list1, list2 = sort_together((list1, list2))
```

Comment: @das-g typo / not paying attention to the doc; fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
newsource=[];newtarget=[]
for valueT in targetFiles:
    for valueS in sourceFiles:
            l1=len(valueS);l2=len(valueT);
            j=0
            while (j< l1):
                    if (str(valueT) == valueS[j:l1]) :
                            newsource.append(valueS)
                            newtarget.append(valueT)
                    j+=1
```

Comment: a couple of lines of explanation would be helpful

Comment: @saiedmomen I posted it in reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829160/sort-list-based-on-values-of-other-list-python-3-x
Here target string is searched over the source string.

Answer (score 0):

**an algorithmic solution:**

```
list1 = [3,2,4,1, 1]
list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']


lis = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(len(list1))]
list1.sort()
list2 = [x[1] for i in range(len(list1)) for x in lis if x[0] == i]
```

**Outputs:** `->` **Output speed:** `0.2s`

```
>>>list1
>>>[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>list2
>>>['one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sort two List Parllerly in python(Sorted By decimal value)**

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
b = ['0.23','80.00','5.01','6.58','1.38','79.06']
c=sorted(b,key=lambda x:float(x))
d=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    d.append(a[b.index(c[i])])
```