# sorting two lists depending on each other, one with dates (python)

Tags: python, sorting

Okay, I'm quite new to python and I hope you can help me with this problem I have.

I'm having two lists, who correspond to each other. Now I want to sort them both in the same way.

I found a solution to that here on the board:
[Is it possible to sort two lists(which reference each other) in the exact same way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764298/is-it-possible-to-sort-two-listswhich-reference-each-other-in-the-exact-same-w)

My problem is now, that one of my lists are strings with dates. I want to sort chronological, but i can't figure ou how to use a key parameter proberly.
Here is the code I have:

```
daten = ["03. Aug 2012", "30. Jul 2012", "25. Jul 2012"]
werte = [10, 35, 22]
daten, werte = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(daten, werte), key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], "%d. %b %Y"))))
```

Now I get a TypeError: must be string, not int

Comment: Seems like you're there - I think the only issue is that the dates are first, so you should call strptime on `x[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `x[0]` rather than `x[1]`:

```
daten, werte = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(daten, werte), key=lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d. %b %Y"))))
```