# Python - How to special sort list

Tags: python-3.x

can anyone advise me how to sort the array by column 'age'?

```
student = {
     0 : {'name' : 'jane', 'age' : 40},
     1 : {'name' : 'pool', 'age' : 11},
     2 : {'name' : 'dave', 'age' : 28}
}

print(student[0])
print(student[1])
print(student[2])
```

results screen

```
{'name': 'jane', 'age': 40}
{'name': 'pool', 'age': 11}
{'name': 'dave', 'age': 28}
```

I tried

```
student = sorted(student, key=lambda student: student[2]) # sort by age not work
```

But it does not work nothing :-(
Thank you for your help

-- EDIT  --
Correct sort list (sorting age)

```
print(student[0])
print(student[1])
print(student[2])
```

results screen

```
{'name': 'pool', 'age': 11}    
{'name': 'dave', 'age': 28}
{'name': 'jane', 'age': 40}
```

Comment: what you have here is a dictionary of dictionaries, and a dictionary is a unnordered structure

Comment: Please edit your post and show how you want the output to be

Comment: Take a look at [OrderedDict examples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes).

Comment: What is the exact result you expect? A single list: `['aaa', 0, 'ccc', 1, 'bbb', 2]`? Two distinct lists: `['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb']` and `[0, 1, 2]`? A list of pairs `[('aaa', 0), ('ccc', 1), ('bbb', 2)]`? Something else?

Comment: I think you forgot an equal sign, i.e. `pole['txt']['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb']` should be `pole['txt'] = ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb']`. The same for `pole['num']`. Am I correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting list based on values from another list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764298

Comment: Soryy all: I tried to write better ;)

Comment: to Andrea Corbellini: There is not an answer to my question :( I have only one dictionary, I have two dictionary.

Comment: @SatNet: now that you have rewritten the question, the answer has changed too :) May I ask you you are using a dict for `student` instead of a list? If you use a `list`, the solution is very straightforward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all `dict`s, not `list`s, so they don't have order; for the inner `dict`s, they don't have numerical keys, so indexing them is an error. That said, you can convert the outer `dict` to a sorted `list` to get the result you want:

```
from operator import itemgetter

students = {
    0: {'name': 'jane', 'age': 40},
    1: {'name': 'pool', 'age': 11},
    2: {'name': 'dave', 'age': 28}
}

# Sort the sub-dicts by age and print
for student in sorted(students.values(), key=itemgetter('age')):
    print(student)
```

Note: Because the sub-`dict`s are also unordered, there is no guarantee that `name` appears before `age` in the output for each student. But this will output the students in the correct order.

Comment: ShadowRanger: Thank you, I do not want to print just I want to adjust!

Comment: @SatNet: Well, you can store the result of `sorted` back to the name `student` (it will be a `list` of `dict`s at that point, not a `dict` of `dict`s) if you need to change the order but don't need to print yet.

Comment: ShadowRanger: student = sorted(student.values(), key=itemgetter('age')); so is it right ? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. Though I'd probably name it `sortedstudents` or just replace the original `student` (unless the keys in `student` are meaningful, e.g. student ID numbers). If they are, you might want to actually write a proper class to represent students, rather than using a collection of `dict` as an ad-hoc organizational structure.

Comment: ShadowRanger : And you advise me please how to add data to the list?

Comment: After creating the `list`, it's like any other `list`. You can call `.append` to add new values; that won't preserve ordering, but if ordering is an issue, you can either call `.sort(key=itemgetter('age'))` on the `list` just before you need ordered data to resort it in place (Python's TimSort algorithm is optimized for cases where the data is already partially sorted, so the cost to do so is not as much as you might think), or (though it's annoying to use when you use a `key` for ordering), use [`bisect.insort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) to insert ordered.

Comment: @SatNet: Note that there is an [existing recipe for a `SortedCollection` that sorts on a given key and preserves sort order on subsequent insertion](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) (also linked from the `bisect` documentation), that might be helpful if you need to store and retrieve student info retaining sorted order.

Comment: ShadowRanger :Very thank you very much for your help.