# Sort a list in python based on the position of its elements within another sorted list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to sort a list in Python based on a pre-sorted list.

```
presorted_list = ['2C','3C','4C','2D','3D','4D']
unsorted_list = ['3D','2C','4D','2D']
```

How can I sort `unsorted_list` such that the values appear in the same order that `presorted_list` has them? That is, in this case the sorted result should be `['2C','2D','3D','4D']`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764298 is another way of sorting one list "based on" another list - a completely different problem that is sometimes, unfortunately, described with very similar language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [5]: sorted(unsorted_list, key=presorted_list.index)
Out[5]: ['2C', '2D', '3D', '4D']
```

or, for better performance (particularly when `len(presorted_list)` is large),

```
In [6]: order = {item:i for i, item in enumerate(presorted_list)}    
In [7]: sorted(unsorted_list, key=order.__getitem__)
Out[7]: ['2C', '2D', '3D', '4D']
```

For more on how to sort using `key`s, see the excellent [Howto Sort wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions).

---

If `unsorted_list` contains items (such as `'6D'`) not in `presorted_list` then the above methods will raise an error. You first have to decide how you want to sort these items. If you want them placed at the end of the list, you could use

```
In [10]: unsorted_list = ['3D','2C','6D','4D','2D']

In [11]: sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: order.get(x, float('inf')))
Out[11]: ['2C', '2D', '3D', '4D', '6D']
```

or if you wish to place such items at the front of the list, use

```
In [12]: sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: order.get(x, -1))
Out[12]: ['6D', '2C', '2D', '3D', '4D']
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this, but the first bit of code seems to give me a Value Error for the very first item in the unsorted list. 

    ValueError: '6D' is not in list

Comment: `.index` will raise a value error if the item is not in the presorted_list.

Comment: @Danica: If you want items _removed_ that aren't in the `presorted_list`, use something like `sorted(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x in presorted_list, unsorted_list), key=order.__getitem__)`.

Comment: The item is part of the presorted list, and it still says that it isnt, I'm not too sure why. 

Here is the unsorted list:
['8S', 'JD', 'AC', '5C', '8D', '10C']
Here is the sorted list:
['2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','10C','JC','QC','KC','AC',
                   '2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','10D','JD','QD','KD','AD',
                   '2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','10H','JH','QH','KH','AH',
                   '2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','10S','JS','QS','KS','AS']
And the error is 
ValueError: '8S' is not in list