# Sorting other columns based on specified column

Tags: python, sorting, multiple-columns, columnsorting

I have a .dat file with three columns separated by spaces [example shown below but in my case there are not column names], and I need to sort the other columns based on the phase column, which is being sorted from least to greatest.

For example,

```
Time    Phase    Mag 
t1      0.1      m1 
t2      0.0      m2
t3      0.2      m3
t4      0.4      m4
t5      0.3      m5
```

And then sort the three columns like this:

```
t2      0.0       m2
t1      0.1       m1 
t3      0.2       m3
t5      0.3       m5
t4      0.4       m4
```

I found an example for 2 column data, [2 column sorting example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764298/is-it-possible-to-sort-two-listswhich-reference-each-other-in-the-exact-same-w/9764364), but it doesn't work for 3 columns.  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can read the file into a dataframe, and sort it on the column `phase`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort pandas dataframe from one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column)

Answer (score 0):

I have saved the below contents to a file called `example.dat`

```
Time    Phase    Mag 
t1      0.1      m1 
t2      0.0      m2
t3      0.2      m3
t4      0.4      m4
t5      0.3      m5
```

The below code should do the job.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("example.dat",delim_whitespace=True) # read the file with whitespaces as the delimiter
df.sort_values("Phase") # sort on the column "Phase"
```

Output:

```
    Time Phase  Mag
1   t2   0.0    m2
0   t1   0.1    m1
2   t3   0.2    m3
4   t5   0.3    m5
3   t4   0.4    m4
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was very helpful.  I also found that there was an extra space at the beginning of the file which resulted in a keyerror, so I used this: 
`df = pd.read_csv('filename.dat', delim_whitespace=True, encoding="utf-8-sig")
df.sort_values("PHASE")`

Comment: That's great! If it helped, please accept/upvote the answer.

Comment: I did but since I am a new member, it won't show until I have a higher 'reputation.'