# Arrays in python, arrays won't line up, ( a beginner to coding)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to code some arrays in python, but when I run the code below, the "sort" and "people" lists won't line up properly ie. the sort is showing the wrong people. I am quite new to python so please keep code simple thanks.
I know a lot of the code is repeated, but I am working on it. The problem area is mostly the last 3 lines but i have attached the rest, just to be sure.

```
 people = []
 score = []
 people.append("Doc")
 people.append("Sarah")
 people.append("Jar-Jar")
 Doc1 = int(input("Enter the test score for Doc "))
 print("Test score:", Doc1)
 Sarah1 = int(input("Enter the test score for Sarah "))
 print("Test score:", Sarah1)
 Jar1 = int(input("Enter the test score for Jar-Jar "))
 print("Test score:", Jar1)
 score.append(Doc1)
 score.append(Sarah1)
 score.append(Jar1)
 sort = sorted(score, reverse = True)
 print("[",sort[0],", '", people[0],"']")
 print("[",sort[1],", '", people[1],"']")
 print("[",sort[2],", '", people[2],"']")
```

Comment: Yes, just realising now, that was a copying error, the sort belongs further down the page, just above the last 3 lines

Comment: In that case, you're only sorting the scores, but not the people's name along with them. To sort them both simultaneously, use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764364/16435355.

Answer (score 0):

Make tuples out of the scores and names so you can keep them together, and put those in a list; then just sort the list.

```
people = ["Doc", "Sarah", "Jar-Jar"]
scores = [
    (int(input(f"Enter the test score for {person} ")), person)
    for person in people
]
scores.sort(reverse=True)
for score, person in scores:
    print(f"[{score}], '{person}'")
```

```
Enter the test score for Doc 1
Enter the test score for Sarah 4
Enter the test score for Jar-Jar 3
[4], 'Sarah'
[3], 'Jar-Jar'
[1], 'Doc'
```