# Sort or remove elements from corresponding list in same way as in reference list

Tags: python, list, sorting, bijection

I have two lists in python of same length:

```
listA = [7,6,3,2,1,4,5]

listB = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

is their some way (probably easy function) to sort listA and change the values of listB in the same way. Means

```
listA_new = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and

```
listB_new = [e,d,c,f,g,b,a]
```

same question about remove duplicates. E.g. if I have some list

```
listC = [1,1,4,4,5,6,7]
```

and

```
listD = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

the result should be:

```
listC_new = [1,4,5,6,7]
```

and

```
listD_New = [a,c,e,f,g]
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Storing several related lists feels like the wrong approach, here. Consider instead storing a single list of 2-tuples, e.g. `[(7, 'a'), (6, 'b'), (3, 'c'), ...]`, or even 4-tuples: `[(7, 'a', 1, 'a'), (6, 'b', 1, 'b'), ...]`. You can conveniently create such lists with `zip( ... )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[i for j, i in sorted(zip(listA, listB))]
```

Output:

```
listA = [7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
listB = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

In [5]: [i for j, i in sorted(zip(listA, listB))]
Out[5]: ['e', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'a']
```

for supporting C and D (removing duplicates):

```
sorted(list({j: i for j, i in reversed(sorted(zip(listC, listD)))}.values()))
```

`.values()` returns ListD:`['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']` and `.keys()` returns ListC:`[1, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Comment: That last bit does not seem right. Using `sorted` as the last step, you just get the sorted letters, not the letters sorted by corresponding numbers. It's the same in this example, but not in general.

Comment: @tobias_k Take a closer look, the inner sort-reveres is to find a first letter that matches. the outer one is to re-reverse the result. it will work in general.

Comment: Nope, sorry, it does not. Try with `listA` and `listB`. No dupes there, but it should still work for those, but it just returns the letters in `listB` in sorted order. Instead of the outer `sorted`, you should just reverse the dict values again.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you : [How to sort two lists (which reference each other) in the exact same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764298/how-to-sort-two-lists-which-reference-each-other-in-the-exact-same-way)

For removing duplicates, you can use :

```py
ListA = [7,6,3,2,1,4,5]
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(ListA))

ListB = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(ListB))
```

Comment: The output is not right.

Comment: @SharimIqbal What do you mean ? Anyway, doesn't matter now as an answer has already been accepted... At least this gave me some reputation lol

Answer (score 1):

About the "removing duplicates" bit: You can start as in the other answer, but also pipe the zipped and sorted lists through a `dict`. In Python 3, a `dict` will respect the insertion order, but it will keep the *last* of each key, so you have to reverse the list when sorting, and then reverse back after the dict stage.

```
>>> listC = [1,1,4,4,5,6,7] 
>>> listD = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
>>> list(reversed(dict(sorted(zip(listC, listD), reverse=True)).items()))
[(1, 'a'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g')]
>>> listC_new, listB_new = zip(*_)
>>> listC_new
(1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
>>> listB_new
('a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g')
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first part.

```py
listA = [7,6,3,2,1,4,5]


listB = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
dict_ = {key:value for key,value in zip(listB,listA)}

listA_new = sorted(listA)
listB_new = sorted(listB,key=lambda e:dict_[e])
print(listA_new)
print(listB_new)
```

###### OUTPUT

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
['e', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'a']
```

---

For not duplicate items. Try this.

```py
listC = [1,1,4,4,5,6,7]


listD = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']


listC_out = []
listD_out = []
for a,b in zip(listC,listD):
    if a not in listC_out:
        listD_out.append(b)
        listC_out.append(a)

print(listC_out)
print(listD_out)
```

###### OUTPUT

```
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```