# Sort tuple list with another list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a tuple list `to_order` such as:

```
to_order = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3,2)]
```

And a list which gives the order to apply to the second element of each tuple of `to_order`:

```
order = [2, 1, 3]
```

So I am looking for a way to get this output:

```
ordered_list = [(2, 2), (3,2), (0, 1), (1, 3)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *tie-braker* policy?

Comment: default tie breaker = stable sort?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate, at least not to the proposed one. The linked question has lists of equal lengths. In the above question, there are multiple `to_order` pairs for one `order` index. The efficient method mentioned in the supposed duplicate (with `mapping`) doesn't work in that case.

Comment: This question is Unclear. It doesn't specify an estimate of the size of the list to be sorted or what to do in edge cases. It additionally lacks research, as there are tons of questions on sorting by another list and on sorting a list of tuples. Why don't any of the answers in those questions apply?

Comment: @jpmc26: I couldn't find any exact duplicate. If you find one, please feel free to comment. Some proposed duplicates either didn't apply or were inefficient. I agree that the question could show more research though.

Comment: @EricDuminil It doesn't matter. It should explain why the other related questions they found don't apply if they don't. It shouldn't be up to every reader to do *all* of that research.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're right. Sorry, I cannot resist looking for alternative, more efficient ways to write something, even for poorly stated questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of tuples according to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814667/how-to-sort-a-list-of-tuples-according-to-another-list)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Algorithm

You can distribute the tuples in a dict of lists according to the second element and iterate over `order` indices to get the sorted list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
to_order = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2)]
order = [2, 1, 3]

bins = defaultdict(list)

for pair in to_order:
    bins[pair[1]].append(pair)

print(bins)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [(0, 1)], 3: [(1, 3)], 2: [(2, 2), (3, 2)]})

print([pair for i in order for pair in bins[i]])
# [(2, 2), (3, 2), (0, 1), (1, 3)]
```

`sort` or `index` aren't needed and the output is stable.

This algorithm is similar to the `mapping` mentioned in the supposed [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12814719/6419007). This linked answer only works if `to_order` and `order` have the same lengths, which isn't the case in OP's question.

## Performance

This algorithm iterates twice over each element of `to_order`. The complexity is `O(n)`. @alfasin's first algorithm is much slower (`O(n * m * log n)`), but his second one is also `O(n)`.

Here's a list with 10000 random pairs between `0` and `1000`. We extract the unique second elements and shuffle them in order to define `order`:

```
from random import randrange, shuffle
from collections import defaultdict
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import chain

N = 1000
to_order = [(randrange(N), randrange(N)) for _ in range(10*N)]
order = list(set(pair[1] for pair in to_order))
shuffle(order)


def eric(to_order, order):
    bins = defaultdict(list)
    for pair in to_order:
        bins[pair[1]].append(pair)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(bins[i] for i in order))


def alfasin1(to_order, order):
    arr = [[] for i in range(len(order))]
    d = {k:v for v, k in enumerate(order)}
    for item in to_order:
        arr[d[item[1]]].append(item) 
    return [item for sublist in arr for item in sublist]

def alfasin2(to_order, order):
    return sorted(to_order, key=lambda item: order.index(item[1]))

print(eric(to_order, order) == alfasin1(to_order, order))
# True
print(eric(to_order, order) == alfasin2(to_order, order))
# True

print("eric", timeit("eric(to_order, order)", globals=globals(), number=100))
# eric 0.3117517130003762
print("alfasin1", timeit("alfasin1(to_order, order)", globals=globals(), number=100))
# alfasin1 0.36100843100030033
print("alfasin2", timeit("alfasin2(to_order, order)", globals=globals(), number=100))
# alfasin2 15.031453827000405
```

Comment: this relies on to_order to be preordered by the first key, else you will get a different output e.g. to_order = [(0, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 3)] will output [(3, 2), (2, 2), (0, 1), (1, 3)]

Comment: @Matt: I'm not sure I understand your point. This algorithm sorts by `order`. If pairs have the same second element, they're returned in the same order as in the input. It's coherent with the description and with every other answer here. If you want to sort each sub list, you can do so in `bins.values()`.

Comment: Thanks, I've also chose to use the dict approach

Comment: @Eric Yeah sorry I wrote that comment with insufficient coffee. What I meant was that it is worth noting that matches may not be ordered as expected

Comment: @Matt No problem, constructive criticism is always welcome. So what would be the expected order for you?

Comment: @alfasin: Cannot reproduce, either with python2 or python3. What did you run exactly?

Comment: You can get a slight, but noticeable performance bump by using `defaultdict`. This also cleans up the code some.

Comment: This is specific to OP's case but presuming that `order` is a 1-starting enumeration to n and `to_order` also takes on values ranging inclusive 1 to n, the dictionary can be thrown out entirely, just index with `i-1` and append like alfasin's solution. Too many assumptions to add as an answer but kinda interesting :)

Comment: @JaredGoguen: I usually prefer `setdefault` because it doesn't require an extra package and doesn't clutter output with `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, `, but changing to `defaultdict` did improve performance by 25%. Thanks!

Comment: @miradulo: Thanks for the comment. I tried your suggestion, it saved 1 or 2% but it assumes a bit too much for my taste. `chain.from_iterable` was a good improvement though, especially if you can use it without converting it to a list.

Answer (score 23):

You can provide a `key` that will check the index (of the second element) in `order` and sort based on it:

```
to_order = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3,2)]
order = [2, 1, 3]
print(sorted(to_order, key=lambda item: order.index(item[1]))) # [(2, 2), (3, 2), (0, 1), (1, 3)]
```

**EDIT**

Since, a discussion on time complexities was start... here ya go, the following algorithm runs in `O(n+m)`, using Eric's input example:

```
N = 5
to_order = [(randrange(N), randrange(N)) for _ in range(10*N)]
order = list(set(pair[1] for pair in to_order))
shuffle(order)


def eric_sort(to_order, order):
    bins = {}

    for pair in to_order:
        bins.setdefault(pair[1], []).append(pair)

    return [pair for i in order for pair in bins[i]]


def alfasin_new_sort(to_order, order):
    arr = [[] for i in range(len(order))]
    d = {k:v for v, k in enumerate(order)}
    for item in to_order:
        arr[d[item[1]]].append(item) 
    return [item for sublist in arr for item in sublist]


from timeit import timeit
print("eric_sort", timeit("eric_sort(to_order, order)", setup=setup, number=1000))
print("alfasin_new_sort", timeit("alfasin_new_sort(to_order, order)", setup=setup, number=1000))
```

OUTPUT:

```
eric_sort 59.282021682999584
alfasin_new_sort 44.28244407700004
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160239/discussion-on-answer-by-alfasin-python-sort-tuple-list-with-another-list).

Comment: How can I apply the sorting of the first and second entry of the tuple and not only the second?

Comment: @user3352632 if I understand correctly you're asking for "lexicographic" order (sort first by the first item then by the second). If that's what you're asking you can try: `sorted(to_order, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))` but IIRC that's the default behavior so you can  also simply do: `sorted(to_order)`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:
`[item for key in order for item in filter(lambda x: x[1] == key, to_order)]`

This solution works off of `order` first, filtering `to_order` for each `key` in `order`.

Equivalent:

```
ordered = []
for key in order:
    for item in filter(lambda x: x[1] == key, to_order):
        ordered.append(item)
```

Shorter, but I'm not aware of a way to do this with list comprehension:

```
ordered = []
for key in order:
    ordered.extend(filter(lambda x: x[1] == key, to_order))
```

Note: This will not throw a `ValueError` if `to_order` contains a tuple `x` where `x[1]` is not in `order`.

Comment: Ev kounis wrote a similar solution with a list comprehension : `[x for y in order for x in to_order if x[1] == y]`. It's extremely slow, though, even slower than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer the `list` objects `sort` function rather than the built-in `sort` which generates a new list rather than changing the list in place.

```
to_order = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3,2)]
order = [2, 1, 3]
to_order.sort(key=lambda x: order.index(x[1]))
print(to_order)
>[(2, 2), (3, 2), (0, 1), (1, 3)]
```

> A little explanation on the way: The `key` parameter of the sort method basically `preprocesses` the list and `ranks` all the values based on a measure. In our case `order.index()` looks at the first occurrence of the currently processed item and returns its position.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,3,3,5]
print x.index(5)
>4
```