# How to custom sort a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list labelled Data which I want to order in the following way:

```
Key order = 'ID', 'GE','FN','LN','MN','EM', 'ST'

Data = ['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki EM:a@b.c MN:0400101010  ST:VIC']
```

I managed to order it while it is in a dictionary like this:

```
d= {'ID':123, 'GE':'m', 'FN':'Amir', 'LN':'Maleki', 'MN':'0400101010', 'EM':'a@b.c', 'ST':'VIC'}

keyorder = ['ID', 'GE','FN','LN','MN','EM', 'ST']

final = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i:keyorder.index(i[0]))

print(final)

[('ID', 123), ('GE', 'm'), ('FN', 'Amir'), ('LN', 'Maleki'), ('MN', '0400101010'), ('EM', 'a@b.c'), ('ST', 'VIC')]
```

but can I do this without making the list into a dict. If not how do i turn the list to a dict?
Thank you!!

​

Comment: and what do you want your end-result to look like? Will it be a string? A list? A what?

Comment: Well you need some way to map which key corresponds with what value.

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814667/how-to-sort-a-list-according-to-another-list

Comment: Is that really a list though, Data in his first message seems to be a string to be parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, make your `keyorder` a dict because `list.index` is an `O(n)` operation you don't want to perform for every comparison the sorting algorithm does.

```
>>> keyorder = 'ID', 'GE','FN','LN','MN','EM', 'ST'
>>> keyorder = dict(zip(keyorder, range(len(keyorder))))
>>> 
>>> keyorder
{'FN': 2, 'GE': 1, 'ID': 0, 'LN': 3, 'ST': 6, 'EM': 5, 'MN': 4}
```

Now you can sort by splitting the part before the `:` from each of your strings and get the corresponding priority from `keyorder`.

```
>>> data = ['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki EM:a@b.c MN:0400101010  ST:VIC']
>>> data = data[0].split()
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda x: keyorder[x.split(':', 1)[0]])
['ID:123', 'GE:m', 'FN:Amir', 'LN:Maleki', 'MN:0400101010', 'EM:a@b.c', 'ST:VIC']
```

(The first two lines here sanitize your `Data` list because it's just a list of one element containing a string.)

Comment: Maybe better yet like `keyorder.get(x.split(':', 1)[0], 99999999)`? There might be contents in the string for which order is not important or so..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis better `float('inf')` or `float('-inf')` as the fallback value if unknown prefixes can occur.

Answer (score 2):

You can used `sorted` with `key`. It allows you to specify an arbitrary lambda expression to sort your data:

```
key_order = ['ID', 'GE','FN','LN','MN','EM', 'ST']
data = ['ID:12,3', 'GE:m', 'FN:Amir', 'LN:Maleki', 'EM:a@b.c', 'MN:0400101010',  'ST:VIC']
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: key_order.index(x.split(':')[0])))
```

This gives as output:

```
['ID:12,3', 'GE:m', 'FN:Amir', 'LN:Maleki', 'MN:0400101010', 'EM:a@b.c', 'ST:VIC']
```

Comment: Thank you so much I realised that I don't need to put it in a dictionary to order it. But I have to display the final result as follows                                              
ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 EM:d@b.c ST:NSW

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

> One line approach:

```
new_list=[0]*len(d)
[new_list.__setitem__(i,"{}:{}".format(j,d.get(j))) for i,j in enumerate(keyorder) if j in d]

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['ID:123', 'GE:m', 'FN:Amir', 'LN:Maleki', 'MN:0400101010', 'EM:a@b.c', 'ST:VIC']
```

> Detailed approach:

```
 d= {'ID':123, 'GE':'m', 'FN':'Amir', 'LN':'Maleki', 'MN':'0400101010', 'EM':'a@b.c', 'ST':'VIC'}

keyorder = ['ID', 'GE','FN','LN','MN','EM', 'ST']

new_list=[0]*len(d)

for i,j in enumerate(keyorder):
    if j in d:
        new_list[i]="{}:{}".format(j,d.get(j))

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['ID:123', 'GE:m', 'FN:Amir', 'LN:Maleki', 'MN:0400101010', 'EM:a@b.c', 'ST:VIC']
```

Comment: Hi this is great but i need to display it like this  --->                                 ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010  EM:d@b.c ST:NSW

Comment: @SakiVandanaDisanayake Your name is long string ;) just kidding , Check my updated solution. And if you like my solution then don't mark it accepted , Just use it ;)