# Accessing list value from another list

Tags: python

Let's say currently i have a list with:

```
L = [[1,'JAYCE'],[2,'AMIE'],[3,'JACK'],[4,'STEVE'],[5,'JAYCE']]
```

and i have another list which contains the names sorted in order:

```
sortedNames = ['AMIE','JACK','JAYCE','JAYCE','STEVE']
```

The output I want to get is, based on the sorted names list, i want to add the ID back to the names in the sorted order which is based off the sortedNames list.

```
finalist = [[2,'AMIE'],[3,'JACK'],[1,'JAYCE'],[5,'JAYCE'],[4,'STEVE']]
```

Note that Jayce appeared twice so even if the first occurrence of Jayce has 5, followed by 1, its totally fine too.

I've been thinking of something like:

```
L = [[1,'JAYCE'],[2,'AMIE'],[3,'JACK'],[4,'STEVE'],[5,'JAYCE']]
sortedNames = ['AMIE','JACK','JAYCE','JAYCE','STEVE']

finalist = []
for i in sortedNames:
    j = 0
    if i in L[j][1]:
        finalist.append(L[0] + i)
    j+=1

print(finalist)
```

I'm getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I'm definitely appending it wrong.

Comment: Can you just sort `L` on the names?

Comment: `sorted` take a key argument `sorted([[1,'JAYCE'],[2,'AMIE'],[3,'JACK'],[4,'STEVE'],[5,'JAYCE']], key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: @f5r5e5d, why not sort the list in place with its own method?

Comment: `L.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` works too.  the `.append()` can be fixed by wrapping `i` in a list: `finalist.append(L[0] + [i])`

Comment: And another.. [How to sort a list according to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12814667/2823755)

Answer (score 1):

So, as long as your data is well behaved, you could group your numbers into deques using a defaultdict:

```
In [14]: from collections import defaultdict, deque

In [15]: grouper = defaultdict(deque)

In [16]: for a,b in L:
    ...:     grouper[b].append(a)
    ...:
```

Then simply:

```
In [17]: grouper
Out[17]:
defaultdict(collections.deque,
            {'AMIE': deque([2]),
             'JACK': deque([3]),
             'JAYCE': deque([1, 5]),
             'STEVE': deque([4])})

In [18]: [[grouper[x].popleft(), x] for x in sortedNames]
Out[18]: [[2, 'AMIE'], [3, 'JACK'], [1, 'JAYCE'], [5, 'JAYCE'], [4, 'STEVE']]
```

I realize it is an ugly wart to use `pop` inside a list comprehension...

Here's an approach using only `dict` and `list`:

```
In [19]: grouper = {}
    ...: for a,b in L:
    ...:     grouper.setdefault(b, []).append(a)
    ...:

In [20]: grouper = {k:v[::-1] for k, v in grouper.items()}

In [21]: [[grouper[x].pop(), x] for x in sortedNames]
Out[21]: [[2, 'AMIE'], [3, 'JACK'], [1, 'JAYCE'], [5, 'JAYCE'], [4, 'STEVE']]
```

Both approaches are O(N).

#### Edit

I just realized that what you *really* want is instead of generating a list of sorted names, just sort `L` using a key directly:

```
In [26]: L
Out[26]: [[1, 'JAYCE'], [2, 'AMIE'], [3, 'JACK'], [4, 'STEVE'], [5, 'JAYCE']]

In [27]: from operator import itemgetter

In [28]: sorted(L, key=itemgetter(1))
Out[28]: [[2, 'AMIE'], [3, 'JACK'], [1, 'JAYCE'], [5, 'JAYCE'], [4, 'STEVE']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function to do this, and lookup the position of the stored name using its `key` argument:

```
finalList = sorted(L, key=lambda x: sortedNames.index(x[1]))
```

Which results in:

```
[[2, 'AMIE'], [3, 'JACK'], [1, 'JAYCE'], [5, 'JAYCE'], [4, 'STEVE']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary by grouping each name to a listing of all the IDs found for the name. Then, `next` can be applied.

```
import itertools
L = [[1,'JAYCE'],[2,'AMIE'],[3,'JACK'],[4,'STEVE'],[5,'JAYCE']]
new_l = {a:iter([c for c, _ in b]) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(L, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])}
sortedNames = ['AMIE','JACK','JAYCE','JAYCE','STEVE']
final_data = [[next(new_l[i]), i] for i in sortedNames]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 'AMIE'], [3, 'JACK'], [1, 'JAYCE'], [5, 'JAYCE'], [4, 'STEVE']]
```

**Edit:**

It is also possible to utilize `sorted`:

```
L = [[1,'JAYCE'],[2,'AMIE'],[3,'JACK'],[4,'STEVE'],[5,'JAYCE']]
sortedNames = ['AMIE','JACK','JAYCE','JAYCE','STEVE']
new_result = sorted(L, key=lambda x:(sortedNames.index(x[-1]), x[0]))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 'AMIE'], [3, 'JACK'], [1, 'JAYCE'], [5, 'JAYCE'], [4, 'STEVE']]
```