# Sort list of tuples based on another list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples for eg.

```
l1 = [(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]
```

I have another list

```
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to sort `l1` on the second value of every tuple according to the order present in `l2`. 
The final result should be

```
l1 = [(1, 'a', 'x'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]
```

As you can see, the tuples whose second value was `a` are present first, then comes tuples with second value `b` and the lastly those which have `c`.

I wrote the following:

```
l = []
for i in l2:
    for j in l1:
        if i == j(1):
        l.append(j)
```

This is pretty straight forward. But I was wondering if there is any pythonic way to get this thing done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of tuples according to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814667/how-to-sort-a-list-of-tuples-according-to-another-list)

Comment: @Georgy Thanks for the comment. That looks like a far more better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with an appropriate `key` function:

```
l1 = [(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
d2 = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(l2)}  # map elements to indexes
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

sorted(l1, key=lambda x: d2[x[1]])
# [(1, 'a', 'x'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use the *sort* method of the list `l1` to sort on the second value of each tuple:

```
l1 = [(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]

l1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

print(l1)
```

If this is not sufficient and you need the second list `l2` for the definition of the order, you can use the *index* method of the list:

```
l1 = [(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

l1.sort(key=lambda x: l2.index(x[1]))

print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dict` that uses the value as key and the index given by `enumerate(l2)` to sort it:

```
l1 = [(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

sorting ={key:idx for idx,key in enumerate(l2)}

l3 = sorted(l1, key = lambda x: sorting.get(x[1],9999999999))

print(l3)
```

Using a dict that way has the advantage of not using `index(...)` on every lookup into `l2`.

You would use `dict.get()` to avoid missing keys causing trouble and just provide a default thats sure to not be in the list so they get put at the end/front.

Output:

```
[(1, 'a', 'x'), (3, 'a', 'z'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (4, 'c', 'xyz')]
```