# Sort list of dicts according to another one

Tags: python, sorting

I have these two lists of dicts:

```
list_1 = [{'document_id': '5'}, {'document_id': '2'}, {'document_id': '4'}]

list_2 = [{'document_id': '4', 'page_id': '1'}, {'document_id': '5', 'page_id': '2'}, {'document_id': '5', 'page_id': '1'}]
```

`list_1` is a superset of `list_2` in terms of the `document_id` if this helps.

I want to

1. sort `list_2` according to `list_1`
2. then sort `list_2` based on the `page_id` for each distinct `document_id`

Therefore, I want to finally have this:

```
new_list_2 = [{'document_id': '5', 'page_id': '1'}, {'document_id': '5', 'page_id': '2'}, {'document_id': '4', 'page_id': '1'}]
```

How can I efficiently do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping of the ordering in `list_1` via a dictionary comprehension.

```
docs = {doc.get('document_id'): n for n, doc in enumerate(list_1)}
# >>> docs
# {'5': 0, '2': 1, '4': 2}
```

Then use the ordering with the `page_id` as the sort keys.

```
list_2.sort(key=lambda r: (docs[r['document_id']], r['page_id']))

>>> list_2
[{'document_id': '5', 'page_id': '1'},
 {'document_id': '5', 'page_id': '2'},
 {'document_id': '4', 'page_id': '1'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is basically the same as [How to sort a list according to another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12814667/4518341) The only difference is you need to get the document ID's from `list_1` first.
2. See [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4233476/4518341)

All together:

```
docs_1 = [d['document_id'] for d in list_1]  # = ['5', '2', '4']
list_2.sort(key=lambda d: (docs_1.index(d['document_id']), d['page_id']))
```