# Sorting a list of lists by the index of a sublist in python

Tags: python, list, indexing, sublist

I'm in the middle of a larger script and need to order a list by the index of the sub lists. My root list contains sub-lists of numbers corresponding to [Latitude, Longitude, Elevation, Distance]. I need to sort the root list by Distance in the sub lists. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting list based on values from another list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: Can you give some example code or lists?

Answer (score 3):

you can use an [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator.itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) to sort the list based on an element of your list:

```
import operator
lst = [...]
lst.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say explicitly what is the value you want the list to be sorted by; in your case this 4th element of each element of your list. One way you can do it is to use `key` keyword parameter of the `sort` method and pass to it a function (lambda) which extracts that element:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,2],[1,2,3,1]]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda s: s[3])
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3]]
>>>
```

Comment: len("lambda s: s[3]") => 14; len("operator.itemgetter(3)") => 22