# Sort list in place using another list of index

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

given

```
a = [1,4,5,3,2,6,0]
b = ['b','e','f','d','c','g','a']
```

order `b` in place, the expected order of `b` is available in the corresponding positional element of `a`.

output will be

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
```

try for other similar input sets.

```
a = [4,0,1,3,2]
b = ['E','A','B','D','C']
```

I can get it done using a third list, even `sorted()` creates a third list, but the key is to sort `b` in place

```
print sorted(b,key=lambda bi : a[b.index(bi)])
```

core of the problem is how to prevent iterating over items in `b` that were already iterated.

Comment: To sort in place, you have `.sort()`

Comment: `B = dict((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(b))` can help you, if you have unique elements in your list

Comment: You can conduct a simple bubble sort on both lists simultaneously.

Comment: `.sort()` also accepts the `key` argument.

Comment: Don't forget that b.index(bi) runs in O(n), which slows the sorting down to O(n^2 log n). That's worse than bubble sort. In addition, it doesn't work if `a` contains duplicate items.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list

Comment: .sort can't access b while sorting b.

Comment: Does `b[:] = make_sorted_copy(b)` count as in-place?

Comment: Interestingly, it seems there is no algorithm which can accomplish your requirement under the restriction that a[] should come out unchanged - given that "in place" means the usual algorithmic "O(c) additional space" and not the pythonic "result is written back to input list". Additional O(n) space seems necessary if the key comes exterior to the data items - can someone with a background in sorting algorithms enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to realise that the items in `b` aren't much use to the key function. You are interested in their counterparts in `a`. To do this inplace, means you can't just use `zip` to pair the items up. Here I use the default argument trick to get an iterator over `a` into the lambda function.

```
>>> a = [1,4,5,3,2,6,0]
>>> b = ['b','e','f','d','c','g','a']
>>> b.sort(key=lambda x, it=iter(a): next(it))
>>> b
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Is there any guarantee made by `.sort` that the key function will be called both in order and only once per item?

Comment: I'd like to strongly support @Eric's question (hence this comment).  Is there such a guarantee?  Otherwise this solution just works due to implementation details of the sorting algorithm.  Actually I'm surprised that the key function is used just in this (here neatly fitting) way.

Comment: @Alfe, it's a good question. I haven't the time to look for an authoritative answer just now. Maybe you can open a new question and get a bigger audience than just me. I'm interested in the answer too.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))[1]
```

Should give:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
```

Since during sorting the `b` itself appears to be empty (see [my question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687515/list-appears-to-be-empty-during-sorting)), you can use that piece of code to do it in-place:

```
b.sort(key=lambda x, b=b[:]: a[b.index(x)])
```

This uses a *copy* of the `b` to search in during sorting.  This is certainly not very good for performance, so don't blame me ;-)

Comment: But that's not in-place for `b`, of course.  So you might not want to use it.

Comment: That's strange.  I tried `b.sort(key=lambda x: a[b.index(x)])` and found that during being sorted, b appears to be an empty list.

Comment: I posted this effect as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687515/list-appears-to-be-empty-during-sorting).

Comment: That's right b is made empty while it is being sorted

Comment: I'd like to discuss that, and would like to give points, so please visit the Q mentioned above :)

Comment: Interesting.  Then my Q should be flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sorter(a,b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        while i != a[i]:
            ai = a[i]
            b[i], b[ai], a[i], a[ai] = b[ai], b[i], a[ai], a[i]
    return b
```

Comment: Nice, this orders both a and b. What if we want to do just b

Comment: @nr.o I think it's not possible. You need to keep track of the cycles that you already sorted and as their number is O(n) you need that many places. Otherwise, nice solution M4rtini, it took me a while to dig out the algorithm 101 from my memory which got lost over the years :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple bubble sort:

```
for i in range( len(a) ):
    for j in range(len(a)-1-i):
         if (a[j] > a[j+1]):
             #swap a[j] & a[j+1]
             #swap b[j] & b[j+1]
```