# Sort list by indexes of another list?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary of dictionaries. Within these subdictionaries, I have two keys - `ui_section` and `section_order` - that determine if the `value` of this subdictionary is shown in a specfic portion of the UI and if so, what order it appears. My dictionary looks like this:

```
MASTER_DICT = {
    'key1': {'ui_section':[1,2],'section_order':1, 'value': 'key1'},
    'key2': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':2, 'value': 'key2'},
    'key3': {'ui_section':[1,2],'section_order':3, 'value': 'key3'},
    'key4': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':4, 'value': 'key4'},
    'key5': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':5, 'value': 'key5'},
    'key6': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':6, 'value': 'key6'},
    'key7': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':7, 'value': 'key7'},
    'key8': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':8, 'value': 'key8'},
    'key9': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':9, 'value': 'key9'},
}
```

The `ui_section` is a list of possible sections the key can appear in. I determine this via the following code:

```
def show_section_ui(master_dict, section=None):
    if section:
        ui_sections = []
        # Find the keys that are part of this section
        for k in master_dict.keys():
            try:
                if section in master_dict[k]['ui_section']:
                    ui_sections.append(master_dict[k])
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        # Order the keys by sort order
        ui_sections.sort(key=lambda x: x['section_order'])

        return ui_sections
    else:
        return None
```

This portion of the code works. The output below shows that order is correct for both sections 1 and 2.

```
>>> pprint.pprint(show_section_ui(MASTER_DICT, 1))
[{'section_order': 1, 'ui_section': [1,2], 'value': 'key1'},
 {'section_order': 2, 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key2'},
 {'section_order': 3, 'ui_section': [1,2], 'value': 'key3'},
 {'section_order': 4, 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key4'},
 {'section_order': 5, 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key5'},
 {'section_order': 6, 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key6'},
 {'section_order': 7, 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key7'},
 {'section_order': 8, 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key8'},
 {'section_order': 9, 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key9'}]


 >>> pprint.pprint(show_section_ui(MASTER_DICT, 2))
 [{'section_order': 1, 'ui_section': [1,2], 'value': 'key1'},
  {'section_order': 3, 'ui_section': [1,2], 'value': 'key3'}]
```

My problem is that the `section_order` needs to have sort orders per `ui_section`. For example, in the above outputs, in section 2, I'd like key3 to be first. My initial thought was to make `section_order` a list as well. But, I'm not sure how to adjust this line to properly account for the list (and to select the correct index to sort by then)

```
ui_sections.sort(key=lambda x: x['section_order'])
```

My intention was to do something like this:

```
MASTER_DICT = {
    'key1': {'ui_section':[1,2],'section_order':[1,2], 'value': 'key1'},
    'key2': {'ui_section':[1],'section_order':[2], 'value': 'key2'},
    'key3': {'ui_section':[1,2],'section_order':[3,1], 'value': 'key3'},
}
```

Getting me output like this:

```
 >>> pprint.pprint(show_section_ui(MASTER_DICT, 2))
 [{'section_order': [3,1], 'ui_section': [1,2], 'value': 'key3'},
 {'section_order': [1,2], 'ui_section': [1,2], 'value': 'key1'}]
```

How can I sort by the `ui_section` and the appropriate index within the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a nice one line code change for you, but you can replace the line you have:

```
ui_sections.sort(key=lambda x: x['section_order'])
```

With this:

```
sort_orders = []
for s in ui_sections:
    ndx = s['ui_section'].index(section)
    # This next line makes the assumption that you ALWAYS have a section_order
    # for every ui_section listed. If not, you'll get an IndexError
    sort_orders.append(s['section_order'][ndx])

    # Magic happens here        
    sorted_sections = [x for y, x in sorted(zip(sort_orders,ui_sections))]
    return sorted_sections
```

---

Output:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(show_section_ui(MASTER_DICT, 2))
[{'section_order': [3, 1], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key3'},
 {'section_order': [1, 2], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key1'}]

>>> pprint.pprint(show_section_ui(MASTER_DICT, 1))
[{'section_order': [1, 2], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key1'},
 {'section_order': [2], 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key2'},
 {'section_order': [3, 1], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key3'},
 {'section_order': [4], 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key4'},
 {'section_order': [5], 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key5'},
 {'section_order': [6], 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key6'},
 {'section_order': [7], 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key7'},
 {'section_order': [8], 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key8'},
 {'section_order': [9], 'ui_section': [1], 'value': 'key9'}]
```

Adding `key8` to the second `ui_section` at position 3, and `key7` at position 4:

```
[{'section_order': [3, 1], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key3'},
 {'section_order': [1, 2], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key1'},
 {'section_order': [8, 3], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key8'},
 {'section_order': [7, 4], 'ui_section': [1, 2], 'value': 'key7'}]
```

---

This is utilizing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618553/189134) answer. First, though, it finds the index that the section is listed in the `ui_section`:

```
ndx = s['ui_section'].index(section)
```

The value at this location is then added to the `sort_orders` list. Note that the code provided does not error check that this is valid (ie. if you don't have a value for the second position), and will throw an `IndexError` if it is not.

```
sort_orders.append(s['section_order'][ndx])
```

Next it zips the two lists together so that you have a list of tuples containing the sort order and the section dictionary.

```
[(3, {'ui_section': [1, 2], 'section_order': [8, 3], 'value': 'key8'}), 
 (1, {'ui_section': [1, 2], 'section_order': [3, 1], 'value': 'key3'}), 
 (2, {'ui_section': [1, 2], 'section_order': [1, 2], 'value': 'key1'}), 
 (4, {'ui_section': [1, 2], 'section_order': [7, 4], 'value': 'key7'})
]
```

Then we sort that based on the first position in the tuple. Then we unzip it and pull back the sorted information. All of that occurs in this line:

```
sorted_sections = [x for y, x in sorted(zip(sort_orders,ui_sections))]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I understood. If you want to sort a list of items according to the order of another list of items, you could do something like this. Step by step, the last line is what need.

We need `itertools.count()`, which is an infinite incrementing range, used to apply an index.

```
import itertools
```

these should be sorted by 'value'

```
>>> values = [{"name": "A", "value": 10},
              {"name": "B", "value": 8},
              {"name": "C", "value": 9}]
```

these are in the same input order as `values`, and should be sorted in the the same order

```
>>> to_sort = [{"name": "A", "payload": "aaa"},
               {"name": "B", "payload": "bbb"},
               {"name": "C", "payload": "ccc"}]
```

Zip the values with their indexes. This annotates each item to include its original order. This is a list of pairs of (object, index)

```
>>> zip(values, itertools.count())

[({'name': 'A', 'value': 10}, 0),
 ({'name': 'B', 'value': 8}, 1),
 ({'name': 'C', 'value': 9}, 2)]
```

Now sort by the key 'value'. The `x[0]` is to get the first item of the pair (the object).

```
>>> sorted(zip(values, itertools.count()), key=lambda x: x[0]["value"])
[({'name': 'B', 'value': 8}, 1),
 ({'name': 'C', 'value': 9}, 2),
 ({'name': 'A', 'value': 10}, 0)]
```

Now retrieve the indexes from the pairs to return the new order of the original indexes.

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[1],
        sorted(zip(values, itertools.count()),
               key=lambda x: x[0]["value"]))
[1, 2, 0]
```

Now use those indexes to map over the to_sort list and retrieve the items at those indexes.

```
>>> map(lambda i: to_sort[i],
        map(lambda x: x[1],
            sorted(zip(values, itertools.count()),
                   key=lambda x: x[0]["value"])))

[{'name': 'B', 'payload': 'bbb'}, 
 {'name': 'C', 'payload': 'ccc'},
 {'name': 'A', 'payload': 'aaa'}]
```

I hope that answers your question. It means changing `MASTER_DICT` to be a list, but I think that's the best representation for it anyway.