# sorting a list of two columns based on one column python

Tags: python, list, sorting

if I have a file (file.txt or file.dat) with two columns (let say x and y):

```
   x      y  
1467153  12309  
1466231  21300  
  .        .  
  .        .  
1478821  10230
```

I want to sort each  (x,y) with x as key value in ascending order. How to do this exactly in python?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I got the two columns in two lists in python so far.

Comment: if you have 2 list then you try this.., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has the built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) which you can use to sort a list.

```
data = """1467153  12309  
1466231  21300  
1478821  10230
"""
l = sorted([list(map(int, line.split())) # convert each pair to integers
            for line                     # iterate over lines in input
            in data.split("\n")          # split on linebreaks
            if line],                    # ignore empty lines
    key=lambda x: x[0])                  # sort by firt element of pair
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[1466231, 21300], [1467153, 12309], [1478821, 10230]]
```

**Edit:** If your input is two lists of integers, do this:

```
xs = [1467153, 1466231, 1478821]
ys = [12309, 21300, 10230]
l = sorted(zip(xs, ys), key=lambda x: x[0])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(1466231, 21300), (1467153, 12309), (1478821, 10230)]
```

Comment: Python is just beautiful.