# Python 3 - Associating two lists

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a code that generates two lists. say for ex -

```
L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
L2 = [22, 21, 23]
```

How can i associate both the lists L1 and L2.
I need to arrange L1 based on L2

For ex - if L2 is increasing L1 should be -

```
L1 = ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

if L2 is decreasing L1 should be -

```
L2 = ['c', 'a', 'b']
```

and so on..

Comment: I believe I understand what you want, but your example is rather confusing at this point (*IMO*)

Comment: See previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, and `c`? Are these variables or do you mean strings `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`?

Comment: @Tichodroma yes they are strings

Comment: Then please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29542554/edit) and make them strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` the lists together, sort them, then unzip.

```
L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
L2 = [22, 21, 23]
x = zip(L2, L1)
x.sort()
L1 = zip(*x)[1]
print L1
```

Result:

```
('b', 'a', 'c')
```