# How to use OpenCV's connectedComponentsWithStats in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, connected-components

I am looking for an example of how to use OpenCV's `connectedComponentsWithStats()` function in Python. Note this is only available with OpenCV 3 or newer. The official documentation only shows the API for C++, even though the function exists when compiled for Python. I could not find it anywhere online.

Comment: For insights on using the labels to mask the image etc, see 
[Python OpenCV \- Connected Component Labeling and Analysis \- GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-connected-component-labeling-and-analysis/)

Answer (score 145):

The function works as follows:

```
# Import the cv2 library
import cv2
# Read the image you want connected components of
src = cv2.imread('/directorypath/image.bmp')
# Threshold it so it becomes binary
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(src,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# You need to choose 4 or 8 for connectivity type
connectivity = 4  
# Perform the operation
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
# Get the results
# The first cell is the number of labels
num_labels = output[0]
# The second cell is the label matrix
labels = output[1]
# The third cell is the stat matrix
stats = output[2]
# The fourth cell is the centroid matrix
centroids = output[3]
```

**Labels** is a matrix the size of the input image where each element has a value equal to its label.

**Stats** is a matrix of the stats that the function calculates. It has a length equal to the number of labels and a width equal to the number of stats. It can be used with the OpenCV documentation for it:

> Statistics output for each label, including the background label, see
>   below for available statistics. Statistics are accessed via
>   **stats[label, COLUMN]** where available columns are defined below.
>
> - **cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT** The leftmost (x) coordinate which is the inclusive start of the bounding box in the horizontal direction.
> - **cv2.CC_STAT_TOP** The topmost (y) coordinate which is the inclusive start of the bounding box in the vertical direction.
> - **cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH** The horizontal size of the bounding box
> - **cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT** The vertical size of the bounding box
> - **cv2.CC_STAT_AREA** The total area (in pixels) of the connected component

**Centroids** is a matrix with the x and y locations of each centroid. The row in this matrix corresponds to the label number.

Comment: I must say that for some reason, I had to use cv2.THRESH_BINARY instead of cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU, then I had to cast src to integer and thresh to float in order for it to work.

I don't know why, but it didn't work otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand why you create the labels matrix when it is then part of the output anyway?

Comment: @ypnos You don't need to for connected components with stats, but do for connected components without stats. I think that part was just left over from me doing it the other way. I fixed it now. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This is a much better description of how this works than the C++ docs have.

Comment: can some one explain how to use the labels? How to check if a centroid is what label?

Comment: Each component in the image gets a number (label). The background is label 0, and the additional objects are numbered from 1 to `num_labels-1`. The centroids are indexed by the same numbers as the labels. `centroids[0]` isn't particularly useful--it's just the background. `centroids[1:num_labels]` is what you want.

Comment: @ZackKnopp Do you also know how I can order the labels by area, width or height?

Comment: @ZackKnopp That's incorrect, you can use the function without stats like this as well: `_, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(segmentation)` :)

Comment: @matchifang You could create an array with the component areas: `areas=output[2][:,4]` Then an array with the numbers of components: `nr=np.arange(output[0])` Then sort them according to area size: `ranked=sorted(zip(areas,nr))` 
With help from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list

Comment: `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats` does not take connectivity as an input argument in OpenCV 3 or 4, and I don't think the function was present in 2. Is this simply a mixup between `conectedComponentsWithStats` and `connectedComponentsWithStatsWithAlgorithm`?
`output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh)` gives the exact same result for me.

Comment: Docs say ltype can be CV_32S or CV_16U - what do these do? I can't find ay documentation on their impact

Comment: Could someone please explain what I could use all of this for?  I am trying to extract individual characters/text and landed here.  I played around with the code above, it works, but how do I utilize it?  I.e. How do I utilize centroids to find the centroids of the text?

Answer (score 21):

I have come here a few times to remember how it works and each time I have to reduce the above code to :

```
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(src,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
connectivity = 4  # You need to choose 4 or 8 for connectivity type
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh , connectivity , cv2.CV_32S)
```

Hopefully, it's useful for everyone :)

Answer (score 11):

Adding to `Zack Knopp` answer,
If you are using a grayscale image you can simply use:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread("path\\to\\image.png", 0)
binary_map = (src > 0).astype(np.uint8)
connectivity = 4 # or whatever you prefer

output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binary_map, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
```

When I tried using `Zack Knopp` answer on a grayscale image it didn't work and this was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

the input image needs to be single channel. so first convert to grayscale, otherwise it causes error in opencv 4.x
you need to convert to grayscale and then the Zack's answer.

```
src = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```