# Java Opencv connectedComponentsWithStats

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to find the centroids of the connected components using the java version of OpenCV (Java 8 and OpenCV 3.2.0.1). However I can't find a detailed documentation on how to exploit the returned variables.
I found this post which explains how the data is structured, but it is for python.

[How to use openCV's connected components with stats in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854197/how-to-use-opencvs-connected-components-with-stats-in-python)

I would enjoy having such an explanation for the java one. For exemple, doing `centroids.get(0, 0);` in Java returns an array with NaN inside even if `centroids.rows();` returns 2.

Comment: You could use contours in java and get the centroids using moments. Have you tried that? If not, which opencv version are you using?

Comment: Please attach you current version of relevant Java code, and mention the exact version of OpenCV you're using.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and OpenCV 3.2.0.1. I didn't tried contours yet because openCv 3.x added connected components functionnality and I wanted to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the row from which you're extracting centroid info as well.

Eg:

```
Imgproc.connectedComponentsWithStats(binarized, labeled, rectComponents, centComponents);     
centComponents.row(i).get(0, 0, centroidInfo);
Point centroid = new Point(centroidInfo[0], centroidInfo[1]);
```

The object centroid would contain the centroid you want. Hope it helps!