# How to extract the largest connected component using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I am using OpenCV in Python to be able to identify only the Leaf presented on the image. I already be able to segment my image, and now I am currently stuck at "how to crop the largest component after I have detected all of them. Below is the codes, please have a look.

1. Using scipy.ndimage, I was unable to advance after find the components:

   ```
   def undesired_objects ( image ):
       components, n = ndimage.label( image )
       components = skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects( components, min_size = 50 )
       components, n = ndimage.label( components )
       plot.imshow( components )
       plot.show()
   ```
2. Using OpenCV connectedComponentsWithStats:

   ```
   def undesired_objects ( image ):
       image = image.astype( 'uint8' )
       nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=4)
       sizes = stats[1:, -1]; nb_components = nb_components - 1
       min_size = 150
       img2 = np.zeros(( output.shape ))
       for i in range(0, nb_components):
           if sizes[i] >= min_size:
               img2[output == i + 1] = 255
               plot.imshow( img2 )
               plot.show()
   ```

However, in both approaches, I'm still getting more than one component as result. Below, you will find the binary image:

[image: Binary Image]

Comment: Can you upload the binary image of which you are trying to find the largest connected component ?

Comment: @ZdaR Updated with the binary image!

Comment: What's the problem with your result ? Your code is not guaranteed to output only one component. It will select all components bigger than your `min_size` parameter. And since you're not clearing your `img2` between different components, they will all end up being drawn on the same image.

Comment: Yes, @Sunreef. I want to remove the min_size parameter to select only the bigger one; however, I'm stuck on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would replace your code with something like this:

```
def undesired_objects (image):
    image = image.astype('uint8')
    nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=4)
    sizes = stats[:, -1]

    max_label = 1
    max_size = sizes[1]
    for i in range(2, nb_components):
        if sizes[i] > max_size:
            max_label = i
            max_size = sizes[i]

    img2 = np.zeros(output.shape)
    img2[output == max_label] = 255
    cv2.imshow("Biggest component", img2)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

The loop on components now finds the component with the biggest area and displays it at the end of the loop.

Tell me if this works for you as I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Thank you, @Sunreef. It works well; however, my results are still poor, I will need to find another approach to solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

Using `cv2.CC_STAT_AREA` for readability:

```
# Connected components with stats.
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=4)

# Find the largest non background component.
# Note: range() starts from 1 since 0 is the background label.
max_label, max_size = max([(i, stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]) for i in range(1, nb_components)], key=lambda x: x[1])
```

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35854198/650885