# Image processing detection

Tags: python, image-processing, detection, defects

I want to detect the circlip in the fixture. if circlip is not present it should give a message "circlip not present".

Comment: lighting needs to be improved. avoid reflections. camera-object pose needs to be improved. picture appears to have been taken at an angle. a frontal view would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Binarization applied to the saturation component gives interesting results.

[image]

vs.

[image]

But the circlip needs to remain tinted.

Comment: @AR_PASSION: in OpenCV, should be `threshold`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @YvesDaoust gives good insights into solving the problem.

Thresholding on Saturation channel as suggested by @YvesDaoust, followed by Morphological closing, and [largest connected component extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055771/how-to-extract-the-largest-connected-component-using-opencv-and-python/47057324#47057324) solves this specific problem.

> Note that this solution is **not general** for all illumination conditions, resolutions, rotation, color, etc...
>
>  But it might work for similar conditions.

[image: res]

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input2.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
s = hsv[...,1]

th = 100
s[s<th]=0

op = cv2.MORPH_CLOSE
morph_elem = cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE
morph_size = 5
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(morph_elem, (2*morph_size + 1, 2*morph_size+1), (morph_size, morph_size))
mph = cv2.morphologyEx(s, op, element)

# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057324
def lcc (image):
    image = image.astype('uint8')
    nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=4)
    sizes = stats[:, -1]

    max_label = 1
    max_size = sizes[1]
    for i in range(2, nb_components):
        if sizes[i] > max_size:
            max_label = i
            max_size = sizes[i]

    img2 = np.zeros(output.shape)
    img2[output == max_label] = 255
    img2 = img2.astype(np.uint8)
    return img2

mask = lcc(mph)

thresh = 20000000

if np.sum(mask) < thresh:
    print("circlip not present")
    res = img
else: 
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)

cv2.namedWindow("img", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("img", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```