# Loss function for semantic segmentation which do penalty for mask separation

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, semantic-segmentation

I have a semantic segmentation task, which I'm solving using PyTorch. I use (dice loss + BCE) as loss function. I know that each image has exactly one mask and I want to do additional penalty if mask was separated into several parts. Which loss function I can use for it?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean? If the mask is "separated", that means your model is predicting the wrong class for parts of the mask, which is accounted for in the BCE loss

Comment: No it means mask mast be connected. If it has some disconnected parts model must be punished. For example "getContours" in cv2 must return one mask only, not more.

Comment: How is that different? If the ground truth is a single connected mask and the model's prediction is a disconnected mask, it means the model made classification errors in predicting the mask which is accounted for in BCE loss. The root cause of a disconnected mask is a classification error.

Comment: I need really big penalty for disconnected mask. I'm ok if it's inaccurate, but it must be single mask not 2 parts.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to penalize the model for predicting disconnected components, we make sure the penalty should be less severe than not producing a mask(s) at all.

So I think a safe way to do that is by penalizing false negative pixels. In this direction you may explore **Focal loss** (https://paperswithcode.com/method/focal-loss). This loss adds penalty to pixels that cause a disconnection.

Also you may explore other custom differentiable losses. Given you always only have one output mask, you may try out a loss that penalizes more contours. Since you apply the loss before thresholding, you can try out **Sum/Mean of Gradients** (use bigger shifts unlike used in edge detection).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add my 2 cents. Some models achieve this by using a Postprocessing step.

Instead of penalising the model by modifying the loss, they keep it as it is. After the model has made the prediction mask, we remove **all but the largest connected component from the mask.** This ensures 1 mask per prediction and prevents disconnected masks. Do check if this approach is suitable for your use case.

There are libraries such as [Connected-Components-3D](https://pypi.org/project/connected-components-3d/) for doing this for 3D masks. OpenCV has support for this as well [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055771/how-to).