# finding largest connected component using opencv 2.4 in python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing code in python 2.7.12 using opencv '2.4.9.1'.
I have a 2d numpy array containing values in range [0,255].
My aim is to find largest region containing value in range[x,y]
I found 
[How to use python OpenCV to find largest connected component in a single channel image that matches a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520487/how-to-use-python-opencv-to-find-largest-connected-component-in-a-single-channel) as pretty well-explained .
Only, the catch is - it is meant for opencv 3 .

I can try to write a function of this type
[pseudo code]

```
def get_component(x,y,list):
  append x,y to list
  visited[x][y]=1
 if(x+1<m && visited[x+1][y]==0)
  get_component(x+1,y,list)
 if(y+1<n && visited[x][y+1]==0)
  get_component(x,y+1,list)
 if(x+1<m)&&(y+1<n)&&visited[x+1][y+1]==0
  get_component(x+1,y+1,list)
 return

MAIN
biggest_component = NULL
biggest_component_size = 0
low = lowest_value_in_user_input_range
high = highest_value_in_user_input_range
matrix a = gray image of size mxn
matrix visited = all value '0' of size mxn
for x in range(m):
 for y in range(n):
  list=NULL
  if(a[x][y]>=low) && (a[x][y]<=high) && visited[x][y]==1:
   get_component(x,y,list)
   if (list.size>biggest_component_size)
    biggest_component = list
Get maximum x , maximum y , min x and min y from above list containing coordinates of every point of largest component to make rectangle R .
Mission accomplished !
```

[/pseudo code]

Such an approach will not be efficient, I think.
Can you suggest functions for doing the same with my setup ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Happy to see my answer linked! Indeed, `connectedComponentsWithStats()` and even `connectedComponents()` are OpenCV 3+ functions, so you can't use them. Instead, the easy thing to do is just use `findContours()`.

You can calculate `moments()` of each contour, and included in the moments is the area of the contour.

**Important note:** The OpenCV function `findContours()` uses 8-way connectivity, not 4-way (i.e. it also checks diagonal connectivity, not just up, down, left, right). If you need 4-way, you'd need to use a different approach. Let me know if that's the case and I can update..

In the spirit of the other post, here's the general approach:

1. Binarize your image with the thresholds you're interested in.
2. Run `cv2.findContours()` to get the contour of each distinct component in the image.
3. For each contour, calculate the `cv2.moments()` of the contour and keep the maximum area contour (`m00` in the dict returned from `moments()` is the area of the contour).
4. Either keep the contour as a list of points if that's what you need, otherwise draw them on a new blank image if you want it as a mask.

---

I lack creativity today, so you get [the cameraman](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-most-common-example-images-used-in-image-processing-and-computer-vision) as our example image as you didn't provide one.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('cameraman.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

[image: Cameraman]

Now, let's binarize to get some separated blobs:

```
bin_img = cv2.inRange(img, 50, 80)
```

[image: Binary Cameraman]

Now let's find the contours.

```
contours = cv2.findContours(bin_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

# For OpenCV 3+ use: 
# contours = cv2.findContours(bin_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
```

Now for the main bit; looping through the contours and finding the largest one:

```
max_area = 0
max_contour_index = 0
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    contour_area = cv2.moments(contour)['m00']
    if contour_area > max_area:
        max_area = contour_area
        max_contour_index = i
```

So now we have an index `max_contour_index` of the largest contour by area, so you can access the largest contour directly just by doing `contours[max_contour_index]`. You could of course just sort the `contours` list by the contour area and grab the first (or last, depending on sort order). If you want to make a mask of the one component, you can use

```
cv2.drawContours(new_blank_image, contours, max_contour_index, color=255, thickness=-1)
```

Note the -1 will *fill* the contour as opposed to outlining it. Here's an example drawing the contour over the original image:

[image: Labeled Cameraman]

Looks about right.

All in one function:

```
def largest_component_mask(bin_img):
    """Finds the largest component in a binary image and returns the component as a mask."""

    contours = cv2.findContours(bin_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
    # should be [1] if OpenCV 3+

    max_area = 0
    max_contour_index = 0
    for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
        contour_area = cv2.moments(contour)['m00']
        if contour_area > max_area:
            max_area = contour_area
            max_contour_index = i

    labeled_img = np.zeros(bin_img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(labeled_img, contours, max_contour_index, color=255, thickness=-1)

    return labeled_img
```

Comment: i will run this and report back .
BTW , really lucid .

Comment: can i draw this contour over a color image (actually, gray scale image was derived from it) ?
Also, i did print 
contours[max_contour_index].shape and got (924,1,2) . It is actually x,y coordinates of 924 points. How can I extract xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax as it will denote rectangular mask whose top left and bottom right coordinate are of my interest ?

Comment: Sure, but you'll need a 3 channel color image to draw over. I read in the image as grayscale in the first lines of code above, so you'd want to read in a color image instead so you can use `drawContours()` with a `color=(b, g, r)` tuple for what color you'd like to draw.

Comment: got it . Now , i have to find top left and bottom right coordinates from the mask.

Comment: that is turning out to be a bit complicated. i tried with following example
-
>>a =  [[[239, 128]], [[240, 129]], [[239, 130]], [[240, 129]]]
>>np.asarray(a).shape
(4,1,2)
>>np.asarray(a).argmax(axis=2)
this seems to give 0 or 1 for each pixel depending on comparison between its x and y coordinate.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you edit the OP with an example image and exactly what you need to achieve?

Comment: okay . the aim is to represent contour as rectangular region . so its top left and bottom right coordinate will be passed to another function which will draw rectangle on the image.
I figured out way to get minimum and maximum x and y coordinate among all pixels of largest component.
it requires calculating - xmax,ymax=contours[max_contour_index].reshape(<number_of_points>,2).argmax(axis=0). so <number_of_points>=contours[max_contour_index].shape[0] . I will try it out .

Comment: @user1371666 you can also simply use `boundingRect()` with each contour to find the bounding rectangle of the contour. See more here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: sir , in above code is it possible that if I get a mask having just 1 pixel (say my input image has just 1 white and i give that 255 to in range) and then when i will try to find largest component , i get error 

number_of_points_in_contour=contours[max_contour_index].shape[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user1371666 I can't reproduce your error, possibly because I'm using OpenCV 3. When I run this on an image with a single white point, it works as expected. Can you edit your original post to show, in the single point case, what your `contours` list looks like? Also please print out all the other variables -- what `contour_area` is when you go through and what `max_contour_index` is and print the full output of `contours`.

Comment: okay, sir.
I had this in my code
h_bin_img = cv2.inRange(converted, lower, upper)
if not np.any(h_bin_img):
    print("this image has no face")
else:
    contours = cv2.findContours(h_bin_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

I will print those cases where inrange gave result but contour being any empty list gave exception .

Currently I simply excluded such cases using 
if not contours:
    print 'empty contour'
    break