# Specifying a rectangle around a binary object to define a spatially-constrained area?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, draw

I am programming in python. I have the coordinate of the center of the object in a binary image. How can I define a bounding box area around the object in python, which starts from left-top most nonzero point and ends in right-bottom most point?

I want to consider a rectangle area around the object to spatially and virtually constrain the working area for an algorithm. For this purpose, how to check whether a point is falling in that region or not?

Your help is appreciated

Comment: are there other objects in the image?

Comment: naieve approach: go over all rows, go over all columns remeber the `min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y` where you encountered white pixel. area is `(minx,miny)`*`(maxx,maxy)` - optimize from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `boundingRect` function as described in this [*Contour Features* tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html):

The `img.png` is the following:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png')
active_px = np.argwhere(img!=0)
active_px = active_px[:,[1,0]]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(active_px)
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),1)
cv2.imwrite('result.png',img)
```

`result.png` is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found out very simple way:

First, I found the indices of nonzero values (here my values are 1) by using [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy-argwhere)

```
pp=np.argwhere(img==1)
```

It will give coordinates like this:

```
[[ 95  63]
 [ 95  64]
 [ 95  65]
 ...
 [197  71]
 [198  68]
 [198  69]]
```

and then,

```
min_point=np.min(pp[:],axis=0)   #output: [95  0] 
max_point=np.max(pp[:],axis=0)   #output: [198 123]
height=max_point[0]-min_point[0]+1  #height=104
width=max_point[1]-min_point[1]+1  #width=124
```

the starting point is (0,95) and ending point is (123,198), I am showing in a figure:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.axis('off')
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0,95),124,104,alpha=0.6))
plt.show(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the code that I have written and works correctly. The code provided by @Alessandro Jacopson is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, since you know the center of the object but not its shape or its height/width, I would do this by finding the connected components in the image. In Opencv, this can be done via the `connectedComponents` function. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854197/how-to-use-opencvs-connected-components-with-stats-in-python) post for an example explaining how to call it from python. This function is quite optimized so unless you want to do real-time compute-intensive optimization you can use it without noticing any overhead.

Once you have the connected components, you can order the pixels of each component (once according to the horizontal component, and once according to the vertical one), and get a bounding box of the form `[left,right,top,bottom]`. After that, checking whether a point falls inside it is trivial.