# separate connected components to multiple images

Tags: python, opencv, connected-components

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTbuW.png) kind of white and black images and i would like to save each white shape to an image that fits the shape's size.

I'm using `connectedComponentsWithStats()` in order to label connected regions, and then I use a rectangle englobing the region to extract it and saving it apart.

```py
img = imread('shapes.png', IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_ , img = threshold(img,120,255,THRESH_BINARY)
n_labals, labels, stats, centroids = connectedComponentsWithStats(img)
for label in range(1,n_labals):
    width = stats[label, CC_STAT_WIDTH]
    height = stats[label, CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
    x = stats[label, CC_STAT_LEFT]
    y = stats[label, CC_STAT_TOP]
    roi = img[y-5:y + height+5, x-5:x + width+5]
    pyplot.imshow(roi,cmap='gray')
    pyplot.show()
```

However, this way I'm having some intersections between shapes as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exgJZ.png)

I would like to have each connected region saved into a separated image without any intersection as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZWAE.png)

---

**UPDATE**

I took a rectangle engobing the interest region and then I ommoted the other labels

```py
img = imread('shapes.png', IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_ , img = threshold(img,120,255,THRESH_BINARY)
n_labals, labels, stats, centroids = connectedComponentsWithStats(img)
for label in range(1,n_labals):
    width = stats[label, CC_STAT_WIDTH]
    height = stats[label, CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
    x = stats[label, CC_STAT_LEFT]
    y = stats[label, CC_STAT_TOP]
    roi = labels[y-1:y + height+1, x-1:x + width+1].copy() # create a copy of the interest region from the labeled image
    roi[ roi != label] = 0  # set the other labels to 0 to eliminate untersections with other labels
    roi[ roi == label] = 255 # set the interest region to white
    pyplot.imshow(roi,cmap='gray')
    pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854197/how-to-use-opencvs-connected-components-with-stats-in-python) detailing the function connectedComponentsWithStats:

> Labels is a matrix the size of the input image where each element has
>   a value equal to its label.

So, this means that all pixels of object 1 have value 1, all pixels of object 2 have value 2, and so on.

My recommendation to deal with your problem is `regionprops`
This is implemented in [skimage](https://scikit-image.org/) (which is great for image processing in python)

You can install it using pip or conda, as detailed [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html)

So, calling regionprops on an array of integer numbers will return a list of generators, which compute pretty much all basic object properties you can wish for. Specifically, the images you want to create can be accessed via 'filled_image':

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import regionprops

# generate dummy image:
labels = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.int) # this does not work on floats
# adding two rectangles, similar to output of your label function
labels[10:20, 10:20] = 1
labels[40:50, 40:60] = 2

props = regionprops(labels)
print(type(props))
```

Now, we can go through each item in the list:

```
for prop in props:
   print(prop['label']) # individual properties can be accessed via square brackets
   cropped_shape = prop['filled_image'] # this gives you the content of the bounding box as an array of bool.
   cropped_shape = 1 * cropped_shape # convert to integer
   # save image with your favourite imsave. Data conversion might be neccessary if you use cv2
```