# Why does find_objects give a bunch of Nones and then range of the whole image?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, scipy.ndimage

I am trying to find all objects detected in difference of frames, I thougt this would give a list of each area detected in the threshold, but [find_objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.find_objects) is giving a bunch of "None"s and a range of the whole image?

```
...
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
(slice(0, 972, None), slice(0, 1296, None))
```

Relevant code can be tested from [here](https://github.com/programmin1/PestDetector)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab

from scipy import ndimage
import os

for img in os.listdir('.'):
    if img.endswith('.jpg'):
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, (int(gray_image.shape[1]/2), int(gray_image.shape[0]/2) ))
        ret, threshimg = cv2.threshold(gray_image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imshow('opening',threshimg)
        objects = ndimage.find_objects(threshimg)
        for ob in objects:
            print(ob)
        cv2.waitKey(0)                 # Waits forever for user to press any key   
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.find_objects) explains when the function returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The `scipy.ndimage.find_objects` function returns

> A list of tuples, with each tuple containing N slices (with N the dimension of the input array). Slices correspond to the minimal parallelepiped that contains the object. **If a number is missing, None is returned instead of a slice**.

I think in your data, the labels are not starting from 1 (0 is background and ignored by `find_objects`). The indices of the entries that are not None are the integer values of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats` for the same.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab

from scipy import ndimage
import os
### for visualising connected component image
def imshow_components(labels):
    # Map component labels to hue val
    label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
    blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
    labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])

    # cvt to BGR for display
    labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    # set bg label to black
    labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0
    return labeled_img

for img in os.listdir('.'):
    if img.endswith('.jpg'):
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, (int(gray_image.shape[1]/2), int(gray_image.shape[0]/2) ))
        ret, threshimg = cv2.threshold(gray_image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh)
        out_image=imshow_components(labels)
        #### stats will have x,y,w,h,area of each detected connected component
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35854198/9605907) for more info on connected component features.