# python 2.7 list sort for advice

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

Suppose I have two lists, one is student ID `studentID=[1,4,2,3,5,10]`, the other is related scores for each individual student in the same index of the list `studentScore=[1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 2.1, 5.0, 4.5]` (which means student with ID 1 has score 1.0, student with ID 4 has score 2.5, etc.), I want to order student ID by score (ascending order), which expected output is `#[1,3,4,2,10,5]`.

My current solution is a bit naive, which setup a student class. In Python 2.7, wondering if any other ways to get sorted result of student ID based on related scores without using an additional class to setup their (two lists) relationship?

Post my current code below,

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, ID, score):
        self.ID = ID
        self.score = score
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.score, other.score)

studentID=[1,4,2,3,5,10]
studentScore=[1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 2.1, 5.0, 4.5]

students = []
for i in range(len(studentID)):
    students.append(Student(studentID[i], studentScore[i]))

sorted(students)
for i in students:
    print i.ID

# expect output: sorted student ID by student score
#[1,3,4,2,10,5]
```

Comment: `sorted(students)` -> `students.sort()` or maybe `for i in sorted(students)`.

Comment: Actually, the solution linked above (about ``sorted()`` vs ``.sort()``) does not answer this question. It's rather this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
sid = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 10]
scores = [1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 2.1, 5.0, 4.5]

print([stid for (score, stid) in sorted(zip(scores, sid))])
```

yields

```
[1, 3, 4, 2, 10, 5]
```

### Explanation

The call `zip(scores, sid)` joins the two lists based on the items' positions into a list of tuples:

```
[(1.0, 1), (2.5, 4), (3.0, 2), (2.1, 3), (5.0, 5), (4.5, 10)]
```

The call to `sorted(...)` sorts the zipped tuple-list by the first item of each tuple:

```
[(1.0, 1), (2.1, 3), (2.5, 4), (3.0, 2), (4.5, 10), (5.0, 5)]
```

The enclosing list comprehension `[stid for (score, stid) in ...]` then only pulls the second argument (here referred to as `stid`) from each tuple and creates a new list while maintaining the new order:

```
[1, 3, 4, 2, 10, 5]
```

Comment: Cool, I do not know `zip` is so powerful!

Comment: BTW jbndir, debugged my original code, my original code output is `1 4 2 3 5 10`, the right result should be `1,3,4,2,10,5`, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You used ``sorted()``, which does not sort the list in-place. You have to assign its result to a variable: ``students = sorted(students)`` or ``students.sort()``.

Comment: Mark your reply as answer. BTW.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually ok, but for smaller tasks like this, instead of declaring a new class, you can use `sorted`'s `key` kwarg:

```
studentID=[1,4,2,3,5,10]
studentScore=[1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 2.1, 5.0, 4.5]
combined = zip(studentID, studentScore)
comb_sorted = sorted(combined, key=lambda pair: pair[1])
sortedID, sortedScore = list(zip(*comb_sorted))
```

You tell `sorted` that the key is the second item from each pair, which is the score.

Comment: Thanks Alex, debugged my original code, my original code output is `1 4 2 3 5 10`, the right result should be `1,3,4,2,10,5`, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

This one liner would sort the scores and ids by the score:

```
studentScore,studentID=zip(*sorted(zip(studentScore,studentID)))
```

Comment: Thanks Uri, debugged my original code, my original code output is `1 4 2 3 5 10`, the right result should be `1,3,4,2,10,5`, what is wrong with my code?