# Python: Lists to Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm writing this question despite the many answers on `stackoverflow` as the solutions did not work for my problem. 
I have 2 Lists, `List1` and `List2`. When I `dict(zip(List1,List2))` the order of the elements inside the dictionary are disturbed.

```
print s_key
print value
sorted_dict = {k: v for k,v in zip(s_key,value)}
another_test = dict(zip(s_key,value))
print sorted_dict
print another_test
print zip(s_key,value))
```

Terminal :

```
[2, 1, 3]
[31, 12, 5]
{1: 12, 2: 31, 3: 5}
{1: 12, 2: 31, 3: 5}
[(2, 31), (1, 12), (3, 5)]
```

I was under the impression that the `[(2, 31), (1, 12), (3, 5)]` would be converted to a `dict`

Any help to understand where or what I'm doing wrong would help! Thanks!

Comment: dicts are unordered. If you need a particular order, use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary like this. I would recommend reading about hash tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a=[2, 1, 3]
b=[31, 12, 5]
from collections import OrderedDict
print(OrderedDict(zip(a,b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort a dictionary, in your case if you wanted to display sorted key/values of your dictionary you can convert it to a list of tuples as you have and sort it by whichever element you want. In the code below it creates a list of tuples and sorts by the first element in the tuples:

```
l1,l2=[2, 1, 3],[31, 12, 5]
print ([(one,two) for (one,two) in
        sorted(zip(l1,l2),key=lambda pair: pair[0])])
```

prints:

```
[(1, 12), (2, 31), (3, 5)]
```

shoutout to [Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list) for the help

Either that or create a list of the dictionaries keys and sort the list then loop through the list and call each key

Or use ordered dict as others have pointed out