# Python Dictionary Sorting

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a python Dictionary

```
var = {'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt',
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv",
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt",
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv",
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt"],
       'modified': [1502974843.8277025, 1501594022.454686, 1501945289.3378062,
                    1501593976.6210368, 1501945143.4162745],
       'row': [9541, 8723, 1664, 506, 2200]}
```

Now I have to sort based on `modified` as key. Without disturbing order.
I have used `pandas` for this:

My pandas solution is

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: var = {'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt', "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt"], 'modified': [1502974843.8277025, 1501594022.454686, 1501945289.3378062, 1501593976.6210368, 1501945143.4162745], 'row': [9541, 8723, 1664, 506, 2200]}

In [3]: search_result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(var)

In [4]: search_result.sort_values('modified', inplace=True, ascending=False)

In [5]: search_result
Out[5]: 
   count      modified                                               path  \
0      1  1.502975e+09    /media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt   
2      1  1.501945e+09  /media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running...   
4      1  1.501945e+09  /media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running...   
1      1  1.501594e+09  /media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Runni...   
3      1  1.501594e+09  /media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running...   

    row  
0  9541  
2  1664  
4  2200  
1  8723  
3   506
```

Can I do this without `pandas`?

Comment: What do you want the sorted result to be as far as containers? A `dict` itself is unordered, so do you want an array or something?

Comment: well dictionaries cannot be sorted in Python. So if you do not want to use a `dataframe`, how about a `list` of `tuples`?

Comment: sorted dictionarty

Comment: Is the idea to sort each `list` value according to its corresponding `modified` element?

Comment: list of tuples can also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the objects as a dictionary mapping, and then sort the list of such objects with the appropriate sorting criterion (specified by `key`). Something like below -

```
var = {'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt', "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt"], 'modified': [1502974843.8277025, 1501594022.454686, 1501945289.3378062, 1501593976.6210368, 1501945143.4162745], 'row': [9541, 8723, 1664, 506, 2200]}

objects = [{field: value[i] for field,value in var.items()}
           for i in range(len(var['count']))]

objects.sort(key=itemgetter('modified')) # you may add reverse=True as per need
```

Comment: what is more efficient way in context with speed. `pandas` or above method.?

Comment: If it is for small number of items, above should be good enough / comparable to pandas. But if you are sorting tens of thousands such objects, pandas will be faster.

Comment: `{field: var[field][i] for field in var.keys()}` => `{field: value[i] for field,value in var.items()}`

Comment: Ah, I was focused on creating the object. Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre, that looks much better.

Comment: Instead of that lambda, you could use `itemgetter('modified')`; it should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion, which uses one dict comprehension to build the output:

```
import pprint

var = {'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       'modified': [1502974843.8277025,
                    1501594022.454686,
                    1501945289.3378062,
                    1501593976.6210368,
                    1501945143.4162745],
       'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt',
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's "
                'Running Shoes_2.csv',
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt",
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running "
                'Shoes_1.csv',
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt"],
       'row': [9541, 8723, 1664, 506, 2200]}

output = {k: [i[1] for i in sorted(enumerate(v),
                                   key=lambda x: var["modified"][x[0]],
                                   reverse=True)]
              for k, v in var.items()}

pprint.pprint(output)
```

This has the output:

```
{'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'modified': [1502974843.8277025,
              1501945289.3378062,
              1501945143.4162745,
              1501594022.454686,
              1501593976.6210368],
 'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt',
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt",
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt",
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's "
          'Running Shoes_2.csv',
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running "
          'Shoes_1.csv'],
 'row': [9541, 1664, 2200, 8723, 506]}
```

As you can see, the output with my code is another dictionary in the same form as your input, but where each list has been sorted according to what I think you want. As you can see, the "row" key-values correspond to your sample output.

Answer (score 1):

The following converts your `dict` to a `list` of `tuple`s and sorts it based on the value of the `modified` key.

```
var = {'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt', "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv", "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt"], 'modified': [1502974843.8277025, 1501594022.454686, 1501945289.3378062, 1501593976.6210368, 1501945143.4162745], 'row': [9541, 8723, 1664, 506, 2200]}
inv = list(zip(*var.values()))
ind = next(i for i, x in enumerate(inv[0]) if isinstance(x, float))  # note 1
res = sorted(inv, key=lambda x: x[ind])  # note 2
print(res)

# outputs:
 [(506, 1, "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv", 1501593976.6210368),
 (8723, 1, "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv", 1501594022.454686), 
 (2200, 1, "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt", 1501945143.4162745), 
 (1664, 1, "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt", 1501945289.3378062), 
 (9541, 1, '/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt', 1502974843.8277025)]
```

- Note 1: There are no guarantees on the order in which the items in `values()` are going to be returned. As a result we must look for the values of the `modified` key and make a note of their `index` to use later while sorting.
- Note 2: If it is the opposite order you are looking for, pass the `reverse=True` argument to the `sorted` function.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's another way to do this in plain Python, with the output in the same format as the input: a dictionary of lists. I use `json.dumps` to make the output look nice. This code isn't quite as compact as Izaak van Dongen's, but I think it may be a little more readable. We use `zip(*...)` to transpose the lists, and again to transpose them back to rebuild the dict. IOW, we transpose columns to rows, sort the rows, and transpose them back to columns.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from json import dumps

var = {
    "count": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "path": [
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt",
    ],
    "modified": [
        1502974843.8277025,
        1501594022.454686,
        1501945289.3378062,
        1501593976.6210368,
        1501945143.4162745,
    ],
    "row": [9541, 8723, 1664, 506, 2200],
}

keys = var.keys()
idx = list(keys).index("modified")
a = sorted(zip(*var.values()), key=itemgetter(idx), reverse=True)
result = {k: list(v) for k, v in zip(keys, zip(*a))}

print(dumps(result, indent=4))
```

**output**

```
{
    "count": [
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    "path": [
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv",
        "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv"
    ],
    "modified": [
        1502974843.8277025,
        1501945289.3378062,
        1501945143.4162745,
        1501594022.454686,
        1501593976.6210368
    ],
    "row": [
        9541,
        1664,
        2200,
        8723,
        506
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your dictionary,

```
var = {'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt',
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's Running Shoes_2.csv",
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt",
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running Shoes_1.csv",
                "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt"],
       'modified': [1502974843.8277025, 1501594022.454686, 1501945289.3378062,
                    1501593976.6210368, 1501945143.4162745],
       'row': [9541, 8723, 1664, 506, 2200]}
```

How about this one line?

```
var['row'] = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(var['modified'],var['row']),reverse=True)]
```

output:

```
{'count': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'modified': [1502974843.8277025,
              1501594022.454686,
              1501945289.3378062,
              1501593976.6210368,
              1501945143.4162745],
 'path': ['/media/anurag/Work/search_script/masterfile.txt',
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Women's Running Shoes/Women's "
          'Running Shoes_2.csv',
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/masterfile.txt",
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/Men's Running "
          'Shoes_1.csv',
          "/media/anurag/Work/search_script/Men's Running Shoes/output.txt"],
 'row': [9541, 1664, 2200, 8723, 506]}
```

Explanations:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sorted(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [1,23,9,4]
>>> sorted(b)
[1, 4, 9, 23]
>>> 
>>> sorted(zip(b,a))
[(1, 1), (4, 4), (9, 3), (23, 2)]
```

Now as you can see sorted only sorts based upon the first value in the tuple
So depending upon it you can get the second value using a simple list comprehension. (*which will be sorted based on first one*)

```
>>> result = [ x for (y,x) in  above_list]
>>> result
[1, 4, 3, 2]
```

The same is what is happening above in the solution. Hope this helps :)

Comment: how `var['row'] = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(var['modified'],var['row']),reverse=True)]`  its returning that value.?

Comment: This link might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list