# Sorting by another matrix works in one case but fails for another

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, valueerror

I need to sort matrices according to the descending order of the values in another matrix.

E.g. in a first step I would have the following matrix `A`:

```
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 0
```

Then for the procedure I am following I need to take the rows of the matrix as binary numbers and sort them in descending order of their binary value.

I am doing this the following way:

```
for i in range(0,num_rows):   
    for j in range(0,num_cols):
        row_val[i] = row_val[i] + A[i][j] * (2 ** (num_cols - 1 - j))
```

This gets me a 4x1 vector `row_val` with the following values:

```
21
10
11
20
```

Now I am sorting the rows of the matrix according to `row_val` by

```
A = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(row_val,A),reverse=True)]
```

This works perfectly fine I get the matrix `A`:

```
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 0
```

However now I need to apply the same procedure to the columns. So I calculate a the `col_val` vector with the binary values of the columns:

```
12
3
12
3
3
```

To sort the matrix `A` according to the vector `col_val` I thought I could just transpose matrix `A` and then do the same as before:

```
At = np.transpose(A)
At = [y for _,y in sorted(zip(col_val,At),reverse=True)]
```

Unfortunatly this fails with the error message

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I am suspecting that this might be because there are several entries with the same value in vector `col_val`, however in an example shown in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618543/3562088) the sorting seems to work for a case with several equal entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, you can't sort multidimensional numpy arrays using the Python builtin `sorted` because the comparison of two rows, say, will yield a row of truth values instead of a single one

```
A[0] < A[1]
# array([False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

so `sorted` can't tell which should go before the other.

In your first example this is masked by lexicographic ordering of tuples: Because tuples are compared left to right and because `row_val` has unique entries the comparison never looks at the second elements.

But in your second example because some `col_val` entries are equal, the comparison will look at `At` for a tie breaker which is where the exception occurs.

Here is a working method which uses numpy methods:

```
A[np.argsort(np.packbits(A, axis=1).ravel())[::-1]]
# array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
A[:, np.argsort(np.packbits(A, axis=0).ravel())[::-1]]
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Explanation:

`np.packbits` as the name suggests packs binary vectors into bit field; it is almost equivalent to your hand-written code - there is one small difference in that `packbits` operates on chunks of `8` and pads with zero on the right, so for example `[1, 1]` will go to `192`, not `3`.

`np.argsort` does an indirect sort, so it doesn't actually move the elements of its operand `A` but just writes down the sequence of indices `I` into `A` which would sort it `A[I] == np.sort(A)`. This is useful when we want to sort something based on the order of something else like in this case.

Comment: Wow that is impressively short! Can you explain a little bit how this works?

Comment: Thanks that helps. So although the calculated "binary values" of the columns and rows are not the same as in my example that shouldn't have any influence on the resulting new order of the matrix, right? For the row sorting I could also write `A[np.argsort(np.packbits(A, axis=1).ravel())[::-1],:]` to make clear that only the rows are taken with every column of them?

Comment: @Axel yes and yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!