# Sort list based on another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numpy

I have two lists in python3.6, and I would like to sort `w` by considering `d` values. This is similar to this question,
[Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list) , though, I could not use `zip` because `w` and `d` are not paired data.

I have a code sample, and want to get `t` variable.

### Updated

I could do it by using for loop. Is there any fasterh way?

```
import numpy as np

w = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
t = np.zeros(10)
d = np.array([3.1, 0.2, 5.3, 2.2, 4.9, 6.1, 7.7, 8.1, 1.3, 9.4])
ind = np.argsort(d)
print('w', w)
print('d', d)

for i in range(10):
    t[ind[i]] = w[i]

print('t', t)
#w [ 0.   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9]
#d [ 3.1  0.2  5.3  2.2  4.9  6.1  7.7  8.1  1.3  9.4]
#ht [ 0.3  0.   0.5  0.2  0.4  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.1  0.9]
```

Comment: *I could not use zip because w and d are not paired data.*  <- What does this mean?

Comment: In the referred question,  X and Y are pair data. But in my example, w and d are not pair data. `sort(zip(d, w))` is not suitable.

Comment: It looks like your example `t` output data is in the wrong order.  You want `t = [ 0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]`, right?

Comment: @TimJohns No. I want to sort `w` by `d`'s values.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I thought I _did_ sort `w` by `d`'s values.  For example, the lowest `d` value is `0.2`, which corresponds to `0.1` in `w`.  Hence why `0.1` is the first element in the `t` output that I provided.  Am I misunderstanding what you want to achieve here?

Comment: zip will make it paired data.you fuse `d`and `w` with `zip`. Sort this fused list and extract the second element of the each tuple in the sorted list.  Look Prune's answer, they have detailed the algorithm

Comment: I'm sorry. My explanation was bad. I added a working sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `argsort` like so:

```
>>> t = np.empty_like(w)
>>> t[d.argsort()] = w
>>> t
array([0.3, 0. , 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.1, 0.9])
```

Comment: GREAT! This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

They *are* paired data, but in the opposite direction.

- Make a third list, `i`, np.arange(0, 10).
- `zip` this with `d`.
- Sort the tuples with `d` as the sort key; `i` still holds the original index of each `d` element.
- `zip` this with `w`.
- Sort the triples (well, pairs with a pair as one element) with `i` as the sort key.
- Extract the `w` values in their new order; this is your `t` array.

Answer (score 1):

The answers for this question are fantastic, but I feel it is prudent to point out you are not doing what you think you are doing.

**What you want to do:** *(or at least what I gather)* You want `t` to contain the values of `w` rearranged to be in the sorted order of `d`

**What you are doing:** Filling out `t` in the sorted order of `d`, with elements of `w`. You are only changing the order of how `t` gets filled up. You are not reflecting the sort of `d` into `w` on `t`

Consider a small variation in your `for` loop

```
for i in range(0,10):
    t[i] = w[ind[i]]
```

This outputs a `t`

```
('t', array([0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0. , 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]))
```

You can just adapt PaulPanzer's answer to this as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am a little confused about my problem. Your answer is easy to understand what I am doing now.