# How to sort a dataframe by values from a list

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, sorting

I have a list with numbers:

```
[18, 22, 20]
```

and a dataframe:

```
Id                       | node_id
UC5E9-r42JlymhLPnDv2wHuA | 20
UCFqcNI0NaAA21NS9W3ExCRg | 18
UCrb6U1FuOP5EZ7n7LfOJMMQ | 22
```

list numbers map to node_id numbers. The order of the node_id numbers matters, they must be in the order of the list numbers.

So the dataframe is in the wrong order.

I need to sort the dataframe by the list values.

End result should be:

```
Id                       | node_id
UCFqcNI0NaAA21NS9W3ExCRg | 18    
UCrb6U1FuOP5EZ7n7LfOJMMQ | 22
UC5E9-r42JlymhLPnDv2wHuA | 20
```

How can I do this?

Comment: maybe this already has an answer here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list

Comment: Not applicable on a dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sorted [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), so you can use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
L = [18, 22, 20]
df['node_id'] = pd.Categorical(df['node_id'], ordered=True, categories=L)
df = df.sort_values('node_id')
print (df)
                         Id node_id
1  UCFqcNI0NaAA21NS9W3ExCRg      18
2  UCrb6U1FuOP5EZ7n7LfOJMMQ      22
0  UC5E9-r42JlymhLPnDv2wHuA      20
```

If want avoid `Categorical` column:

```
df = df.iloc[df['node_id'].map({v: k for k, v in enumerate(L)}).argsort()]
```

Comment: Thanks, any difference to the one liner from YOBEN_S?

Comment: @Vega - Another solution is wrong. Because missing `ordered=True`

Answer (score 1):

I will do

```
l=[18, 22, 20]
df=df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.node_id, l).argsort()]
Out[79]: 
                         Id  node_id
1  UCFqcNI0NaAA21NS9W3ExCRg       18
2  UCrb6U1FuOP5EZ7n7LfOJMMQ       22
0  UC5E9-r42JlymhLPnDv2wHuA       20
```