# Python 3.x -- sort one list based on another list and then return both lists sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**Problem:** I would like to sort one list based on another list and then return both lists sorted.

I'm doing it like this:

```
points = [4,7,3,2,7]
candidates = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

ordered_candidates = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(points, candidates), reverse=True)]
ordered_points = sorted(points, reverse=True)
```

**Question**: Is it possible to merge the last two lines into one line?

I found question: [Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list) but it's not exactly what I'm  asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to merge the last two lines into one line?

Yes it is. `ordered_candidates` excludes the points from the result, since you only choose the *candidates* with `[x for _, x in...]`. This basically only selects the *second* item from each tuple. Additionally, `ordered_points` sorts *only* the points. They both also sort in reverse with `reverse=True`.

Seems like you can just modify `ordered_candidates` to include both items in the `(point, candidate)` pairs.

```
>>> points = [4,7,3,2,7]
>>> candidates = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> sorted(zip(points, candidates), reverse=True)
[(7, 'e'), (7, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (2, 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by:

- changing, slightly, what save in the inner list comprehension
- unpacking that list comprehension
- zipping that unpacked data, which stores the results into two tuples the same length as the original inputs, but with the appropriate sorting preserved
- unpacking the results into two variables on a single line

````
points = [4,7,3,2,7]
candidates = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

ordered_candidates, ordered_points = zip(*[(p, c) for p, c in sorted(zip(points, candidates), reverse=True)])```
````