# Is there a way of sorting parallel lists of integers and strings in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists in my program, for example:

**[user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7]**

**[32, 54, 2, 684, 23, 876, 12]**

The first list is the username, and the second list is how many messages the user sent.

Is there a way to sort the second list in descending order whilst also rearranging the first list to correspond to the new order of the second list?

Comment: First of all, does this answer your question? [Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list). Second, you might consider switching to a `dict` instead of 2 lists

Comment: `lst1, lst2 = zip(*sorted(zip(lst1, lst2), key=lambda k: -k[1]))` where `lst1` is your first list, `lst2` second

Comment: `zip` function allows parallel iteration