# How to sort tuple in list based on value in other list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list contaning tuples

```
a = [('TV-MA', 1348), ('TV-14', 1038), ('R', 506), ('TV-PG', 432), ('PG-13', 286), ('NR', 202), ('PG', 183), ('TV-G', 80), ('TV-Y7', 69), ('TV-Y', 41)]
```

I want to sort a based on value in another list

```
b = ['TV-MA', 'TV-14', 'TV-PG', 'R', 'PG-13', 'NR', 'PG', 'TV-Y7', 'TV-G', 'TV-Y']
```

How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with the key that returns the index of element from the second list

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: b.index(x[0]))
[('TV-MA', 1348), ('TV-14', 1038), ('TV-PG', 432), ('R', 506), ('PG-13', 286), ('NR', 202), ('PG', 183), ('TV-Y7', 69), ('TV-G', 80), ('TV-Y', 41)]
```

To speedup the index lookup, you can create a tmp dict that contains the index of the various elements in the second list

```
>>> d = dict(zip(b, range(len(b))))
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: d[x[0]])
[('TV-MA', 1348), ('TV-14', 1038), ('TV-PG', 432), ('R', 506), ('PG-13', 286), ('NR', 202), ('PG', 183), ('TV-Y7', 69), ('TV-G', 80), ('TV-Y', 41)]
```

Answer (score 2):

use this -

```
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
b
```

```
[('TV-MA', 1348),
 ('TV-14', 1038),
 ('R', 506),
 ('TV-PG', 432),
 ('PG-13', 286),
 ('NR', 202),
 ('PG', 183),
 ('TV-G', 80),
 ('TV-Y7', 69),
 ('TV-Y', 41)]
```

If you only want the first element then -

```
b = [i[0] for i in b]
b
```

```
['TV-MA', 'TV-14', 'R', 'TV-PG', 'PG-13', 'NR', 'PG', 'TV-G', 'TV-Y7', 'TV-Y']
```

In one line -

```
b = [i[0] for i in sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)]
b
```

```
['TV-MA', 'TV-14', 'R', 'TV-PG', 'PG-13', 'NR', 'PG', 'TV-G', 'TV-Y7', 'TV-Y']
```