# Sort in descending order python

Tags: python

I will like to sort by position in descending order.
Given:

```
name = ["Shawn", "Patrick", "Nancy", "Viola"]

position = [3,1,4,2]
   
l =[name,positions]    

l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: So what is your expected outcome?

Comment: `NameError: name 'positions' is not defined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: `list(zip(*sorted(zip(name, position), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Change `l = [name, positions]` to `l = list(zip(name,position))`:

```py
>>> name = ["Shawn", "Patrick", "Nancy", "Viola"]
>>> position = [3,1,4,2]
>>> l = list(zip(name,position))
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: -x[1])
>>> l
[('Nancy', 4), ('Shawn', 3), ('Viola', 2), ('Patrick', 1)]
```

Also note the modified sort key for descending order.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `zip` to pair up items in corresponding positions. (This will produce an iterable, so either convert to list or use `sorted` rather than `.sort`.)
- To reverse the order, either use `-x[1]` as the key, or pass `reverse=True`.
- (typo) Name the `position` variable consistently.
- (style) Avoid using `l` as a variable name, as it can be confused with `1` and `I`.

```
name = ["Shawn", "Patrick", "Nancy", "Viola"]
position = [3, 1, 4, 2]
l = zip(name, position)
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```