# Sorting tuple list based on another list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

There are two lists.

```
list1 = [('ST00003', '009830'), ('ST00003', '005490'), ('ST00003', '005830'), ('ST00003', '251270'), ('ST00002', '111710')]
list2 = ['111710', '005830', '009830', '005490', '251270']
```

I want to sort list1 in order of list2.

```
list3 = [('ST00002', '111710'), ('ST00003', '005830'), ('ST00003', '009830'), ('ST00003', '005490'), ('ST00003', '251270')]
```

I want to make it like list3 when it's sorted. Is there any good way?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer: I think the sort order is the index into `list2`, not the values themselves.

Comment: All you need to do is `sorted(list1, key=lambda t: list2.index(t[1]))`.

Comment: But note that `list2.index(t[1])` will be `O(n^2)`, so less good as `len(list2)` gets large.

Answer (score 2):

I did it my making an intermediate `dict` which maps from the number field to the index in `list2`:

```py
list1 = [('ST00003', '009830'), ('ST00003', '005490'), ('ST00003', '005830'), ('ST00003', '251270'), ('ST00002', '111710')]
list2 = ['111710', '005830', '009830', '005490', '251270']

map2 = {value:index for index,value in enumerate(list2)}
print(map2)

list3 = sorted(list1, key = lambda i: map2[i[1]])
print(list3)
```

Output as required.

Comment: It's the desired result. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With a dict to look up the items:

```
>>> [*map({i[1]: i for i in list1}.get, list2)]
[('ST00002', '111710'), ('ST00003', '005830'), ('ST00003', '009830'), ('ST00003', '005490'), ('ST00003', '251270')]
```

(I'm assuming that you didn't provide a bad example, i.e., that if your real data isn't such a 1-to-1 correspondence between `list1` and `list2`, you would'n't have made it look like it is.)

Answer (score 0):

Since second element of tuple is key used to sort, reverse the tuples and create a dict and use it for lookup.
Minor assumption: This code will only produce correct results if the number of elements in the list1 and list2 are same.

Code:

```
list1 = [('ST00003', '009830'), ('ST00003', '005490'), ('ST00003', '005830'), ('ST00003', '251270'), ('ST00002', '111710')]
list2 = ['111710', '005830', '009830', '005490', '251270']

# desired list3 = [('ST00002', '111710'), ('ST00003', '005830'), ('ST00003', '009830'), ('ST00003', '005490'), ('ST00003', '251270')]
list1_rev_tuples = [(ele[1], ele[0]) for ele in list1]
dct = dict(list1_rev_tuples)
print(dct)
list3 = [(dct[ele], ele) for ele in list2]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
{'009830': 'ST00003', '005490': 'ST00003', '005830': 'ST00003', '251270': 'ST00003', '111710': 'ST00002'}
[('ST00002', '111710'), ('ST00003', '005830'), ('ST00003', '009830'), ('ST00003', '005490'), ('ST00003', '251270')]
```