# Sorting arrays in python

Tags: python, list

I have an array of variable numbers.
I have another array that I want to be the of labels for the numbers array.

```
myList = [T1_sum, T2_sum, T3_sum, T4_sum, T5_sum, T6_sum, T7_sum, T8_sum, T9_sum, T10_sum]
mylables = ["cats", "dogs", "monkey", "fish", "rabbit", "owl", "pig", "goat", "cow", "bull"]
```

I want to sort the array by highest to lowest value. I did this by:

```
sortedlist = sorted(myList, reverse=True)
```

However, how do I rearrange the labels so that they are in line with the values?
I need to keep it so that a `sortedlabellist` is its own individual array (for future things). so i will probably have to link the values to the labels and then pull out a `sortedlabellist` separately?

Comment: By the looks of it, you should be using a dictionary structure - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: turn it into a [dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary/) & you can pull the dictionary 'labels' at anytime & put them into a list with `label_list = list(my_dict)`

Comment: As a more general rule, any time you have two data structures that need to be kept perfectly in sync, it's a very strong clue that they should be a single data structure.  A dictionary is one option; another would be to make this a single list of tuples (or maybe `NamedTuple`s).  Either of those approaches makes the sorting problem very easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list based on values from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid using a dictionary you can use `zip` and unzip (`*zip`):

```
sortedList, sortedLables = zip(*sorted(zip(myList, mylables), reverse=True))
```

In fact, the unpacking returns the sequences as tuples. If you need it as list, you can cast it to list again:

```
sortedList, sortedLables = list(sortedList), list(sortedLables)
print(sortedList)
print(sortedLables)

# Output
['T9_sum', 'T8_sum', 'T7_sum', 'T6_sum', 'T5_sum', 'T4_sum', 'T3_sum', 'T2_sum', 'T1_sum', 'T10_sum']
['cow', 'goat', 'pig', 'owl', 'rabbit', 'fish', 'monkey', 'dogs', 'cats', 'bull']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just form a dictionary in order to maintain the order of both the lists while sorting:

```py
>>> labelToSum = {key:value for key,value in zip(mylables, myList)}
>>> labelToSum
{'cats': 2,
 'dogs': 4,
 'monkey': 1,
 'fish': 7,
 'rabbit': 3,
 'owl': 8,
 'pig': 4,
 'goat': 5,
 'cow': 9,
 'bull': 4}
```

Then you can just sort this dictionary based on values, like this:

```py
>>> {k: v for k, v in reversed(sorted(labelToSum.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))}
{'cow': 9,
 'owl': 8,
 'fish': 7,
 'goat': 5,
 'bull': 4,
 'pig': 4,
 'dogs': 4,
 'rabbit': 3,
 'cats': 2,
 'monkey': 1}
```

Comment: This assumes the keys are unique (probably okay here). Also sorting and putting back into a dict fails prior to python 3.7/3.6 where dicts don't retain insertion order

Comment: You don't need the dictionary comprehension. Just do: `labelToSum = dict(zip(myTables, myList))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension and zip():

```
[x for _, x in sorted(zip(myList, mylables), reverse=True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
sortedlabellist = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(myList, mylables), reverse = True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the data structures you've choosen are not adecuate. If you just want to associate each element of **myList** with elements of **mylables** then a list of tuples [("cats", T1_sum), ("dogs", T2_sum), ...] should be enough.

Assuming both lists have same length (so as not to lose information),

```
zip(mylables,myList)
```

gets a list of tuples. Then you should sort it by first component.

Now, if you have more information about the lists, say every element in **mylables** (["cats", "dogs", ...]) appears only once, then choosing a dictionary (data structure in python) with **mylables** elements as keys and **myList** elements as values will make search operations and sorting operations more efficient.

Assuming both lists have the same length (so as not to lose information),

```
myDictionary = dict(zip(mylables,myList))
```

gets you a dictionary that can be sorted with the next line:

```
sorted(myDictionary)
```