# TkinterTreeCtrl MultiListBox re-sort list when clicking column headers

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a MultiBoxList from [TkinterTreeCtrl](http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/) in a window with multiple columns, some are numeric, some alphabetical (I believe as far as this cares, they're all alphanumeric). This has been populated from a database.

I would like to be able to click the column headers to either: switch which column is being used to sort the list, or: reverse the sort order (i.e. descending ascending) if that column is already being used to sort.

Below is an outline of one of these lists.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import TkTreectrl as treectrl

root = Tk()
root.title("Columns Demo")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

# ========== Pickers Panel =============
top_panel = ttk.Frame(mainframe, padding="3 3 12 12")
top_panel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

demo_picker_vscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(top_panel)
demo_picker_hscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(top_panel, orient='horizontal')
demo_picker_vscroll.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, W, S))
demo_picker_hscroll.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(N, W, E))
demo_picker_label = ttk.Label(top_panel, text="Table:", anchor=CENTER)
demo_picker_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))
demo_picker = treectrl.MultiListbox(top_panel, yscrollcommand=demo_picker_vscroll.set,
                                      xscrollcommand=demo_picker_hscroll.set)
demo_picker.focus_set()
demo_picker.configure(selectcmd=None, selectmode="single", width=300, height=200)
demo_picker.config(columns=("Column1", "Column2"))
demo_picker.column_configure(0, width=200)
demo_picker.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E, S, N))
demo_picker_vscroll.config(command=demo_picker.yview)
demo_picker_hscroll.config(command=demo_picker.xview)

for i, row in enumerate(range(50)):
    demo_picker.insert(i, i, row)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Image of Tkinter Window displaying a list with 2 columns as defined by the code above]

In my actual use case one of these columns could contain assorted strings not just numbers, others may be timestamps, so sorting them becomes very needed.

Further, I have a `date` column in one of my panels like this. Is there a particular datetime formatting that's still human readable but will obey sensible ordering? `YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` should work for this right?

Lastly as a side question, can I make the text from these copy-pastable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good example of `MultiListbox` with column sorting in the demo folder of the source code of [TkinterTreeCtrl](http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/). I have adapted this example, with integers in the first column and dates in the second.

It is based on the `.sort` method of the listbox

```
demo_picker.sort(column=nb, command=sort_fct, mode='increasing'/'decreasing')
```

where the documentation for the `command` option states

> Use command as a comparison command. To compare two items, evaluate a
> command with the numerical ids of the two items passed as arguments.
> The comamnd should return an integer less than, equal to, or greater
> than zero if the first item is to be considered less than, equal to,
> or greater than the second, respectively.

Therefore `sort_fct(item1, item2)` has to retrieve the values for the items in the target column and convert them to an appropriate type to perform the comparison (e.g. int, datetime, ...)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import TkTreectrl as treectrl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

root = Tk()
root.title("Columns Demo")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

# ========== Pickers Panel =============
top_panel = ttk.Frame(mainframe, padding="3 3 12 12")
top_panel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

demo_picker_vscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(top_panel)
demo_picker_hscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(top_panel, orient='horizontal')
demo_picker_vscroll.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, W, S))
demo_picker_hscroll.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(N, W, E))
demo_picker_label = ttk.Label(top_panel, text="Table:", anchor=CENTER)
demo_picker_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))
demo_picker = treectrl.MultiListbox(top_panel, yscrollcommand=demo_picker_vscroll.set,
                                      xscrollcommand=demo_picker_hscroll.set)
demo_picker.focus_set()
demo_picker.configure(selectcmd=None, selectmode="single", width=300, height=200)
demo_picker.config(columns=("Column1", "Column2"))
demo_picker.column_configure(0, width=200)
demo_picker.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E, S, N))
demo_picker_vscroll.config(command=demo_picker.yview)
demo_picker_hscroll.config(command=demo_picker.xview)

now = datetime.now()
for i, row in enumerate(range(50)):
    demo_picker.insert(i, row, (now - timedelta(i)).strftime("%H:%M %d-%m-%Y"))


# add arrow icons to the column headers first
demo_picker.column_configure(demo_picker.column(0), arrow='down', arrowgravity='right')
demo_picker.column_configure(demo_picker.column(1), arrow='down', arrowgravity='right')

# set sortorder flags indicating the sorting order for every column
sortorder_flags = {0: 'increasing', 1: 'increasing'}

# custom sorting functions
def sort_0(item1, item2):
    i1, i2 = demo_picker.index(item=item1), demo_picker.index(item=item2)
    a = int(demo_picker.get(i1)[0][0])
    b = int(demo_picker.get(i2)[0][0])

    if b > a:
        return -1
    elif b < a:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def sort_1(item1, item2):
    i1, i2 = demo_picker.index(item=item1), demo_picker.index(item=item2)
    a = datetime.strptime(demo_picker.get(i1)[0][1], "%H:%M %d-%m-%Y")
    b = datetime.strptime(demo_picker.get(i2)[0][1], "%H:%M %d-%m-%Y")

    if b > a:
        return -1
    elif b < a:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# now create a common sort command for all columns
def sort_list(event):
    # do the sorting
    if event.column == 0:
        demo_picker.sort(column=0, command=sort_0, mode=sortorder_flags[0])
    else:
        demo_picker.sort(column=1, command=sort_1, mode=sortorder_flags[1])
    # switch the sortorder flag and turn the arrow icons upside down
    if sortorder_flags[event.column] == 'increasing':
        demo_picker.column_configure(demo_picker.column(event.column), arrow='up')
        sortorder_flags[event.column] = 'decreasing'
    else:
        demo_picker.column_configure(demo_picker.column(event.column), arrow='down')
        sortorder_flags[event.column] = 'increasing'

# finally register the sort command
demo_picker.notify_install('<Header-invoke>')
demo_picker.notify_bind('<Header-invoke>', sort_list)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!! I've applied this successfully to my case. Only issue is it hangs for quite some time on lengthy lists. Not the end of the world though

Comment: Just a thought on speed for long lists. If I format my datetime strings as year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds, I could just rely on string sorts instead of the converting 100,000 datetime strings back into datetime objects? Alternatively could I have a "hidden" column that contains the unix timestamp floats and when clicking the human-readable date column it actually calls for data from the hidden column?

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 I have not seen an equivalent of `displaycolumns` option of the `ttk.Treeview` for the `MultiListbox` so I am not sure it is possible to have a hidden column, so using a "year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds" format and the default sorting should work fine.

Comment: No worries! This does make it rather hard to sort very long lists in reasonable time unfortunately. Might it be more worth while to sort the data more "natively" using builtin `sort()` and then re-load the data into the `Multilistbox`? perhaps like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618543/9311137. I'll give it a go later and see if I get an improvement. Might also be worth trying with numpy arrays