# Sort nested list based on pattern in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, nested-lists

I have following problem:

List to be sorted:

```
[['[check116] Ensure ...', 'azure-ad-role-manager ...'],
['[check28] Ensure ...', 'eu-west-1: Key ...', 'eu-central-1: Key ...'], 
['[check41] Ensure ...', 'Found ...']]
```

Pattern:

```
["[check28] Ensure ...",
"[check116] Ensure ...",
"[check41] Ensure ..."]
```

Desired output:

```
[['[check28] Ensure ...', 'eu-west-1: Key ...', 'eu-central-1: Key ...'], 
['[check116] Ensure ...', 'azure-ad-role-manager ...'],
['[check41] Ensure ...', 'Found ...']]
```

I've tried:
[Sorting list based on values from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)
and few other solutions - but they mainly base on sorting the pattern's int values, and it's not the case in my problem.

Thanks in advance for any hints or solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list.index` in your `key=` function:

```py
lst = [
    ["[check116] Ensure ...", "azure-ad-role-manager ..."],
    ["[check28] Ensure ...", "eu-west-1: Key ...", "eu-central-1: Key ..."],
    ["[check41] Ensure ...", "Found ..."],
]

pattern = [
    "[check28] Ensure ...",
    "[check116] Ensure ...",
    "[check41] Ensure ...",
]

out = sorted(lst, key=lambda k: pattern.index(k[0]))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ["[check28] Ensure ...", "eu-west-1: Key ...", "eu-central-1: Key ..."],
    ["[check116] Ensure ...", "azure-ad-role-manager ..."],
    ["[check41] Ensure ...", "Found ..."],
]
```