# Sort dictionary based on values from a list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How can I sort a dictionary using the values from a list?

```
names = ['bread', 'banana', 'apple']
prices = ['2', '4', '1']
...

dict = {'name': names, 'price': prices}
```

`dict` is now `{'name': ['bread', 'banana', 'apple'], 'price': ['2', '4', '1']}`

I want to sort the dictionary in a way that the first name corresponds to the lower price.

Is this possible to achieve with sorting on a dictionary?

**Example**

`sorted_dict = {'name': ['apple', 'bread', 'banana'], price: ['1', '2', '4']}`

Comment: Can you show an actual example?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you mean. Do you mean to keep names ordering the same and sort prices separate or keep their appropriate correlations as they are before sorting?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited to clarify what I wanted

Comment: So you want to sort two lists. This has nothing to do with a dictionary. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list

Comment: I thought the 2 lists had some kind of connection since they're a part of the same dictionary like an HashMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, **you want to sort the first list (in name) based on the values of the second list (in price)**.

If that's what you want, then a quick way is to use `pandas`, since the data structure you have (`dict of lists`), fits really nicely with a `pd.DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(d).sort_values('price').to_dict('list')
```

```
{'name': ['apple', 'bread', 'banana'], 'price': ['1', '2', '4']}
```

---

Added the example as per OPs modified request -

```
names = ['bread', 'banana', 'apple']
prices = ['2', '4', '1']
description = ['a','x','b']
...

d = {'name': names, 'price': prices, 'description':description}


pd.DataFrame(d).sort_values('price').to_dict('list')
```

```
{'name': ['apple', 'bread', 'banana'],
 'price': ['1', '2', '4'],
 'description': ['b', 'a', 'x']}
```

Comment: will this work if I have another parameter like a description? `dict = {'name': names, 'price': prices, 'description': descriptions}`

Comment: yea, you can add more variables in `sorted_values(['price', 'description'])`

Comment: The best way i can suggest is to try it. If you face any issues, then let me know

Comment: but in this case description is like the name I just want it to follow the price sorting

Comment: all values will be sorted by the price column if you only keep price in `sort_values`. Try the code and check the output :)

Comment: I get this error `File "C:\Users\AndreClerigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1779, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'prices'` I've also tried price instead of prices and got the same

Comment: price is what you hvae in the dictionary dont you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237247/discussion-between-andre-clerigo-and-akshay-sehgal).