# Sort two lists one string other float

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
one = ['allen', 'steve', 'george', 'max']
two = [88.63, 33.99, 72.66, 92.11]
```

I would like two lists sorted as below.

```
one = ['max', 'allen', 'george', 'steve']
two = [92.11, 88.63, 72.66 33.99]
```

What I have tried

```
one, two = sorted(zip(one, two))
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6618515/3001761

Comment: list `one` is not list of `str`. It's not even valid one, unless all elements are names, but not defined here.

Comment: why does max come before allen, but allen comes before george?

Comment: @ph140 The names are sorted according to the numbers list.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that:

```
one, two = zip(*sorted(zip(one, two), key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the lists into a matrix and then sort the matrix using the numbers.  The matrix is a 2D list that would group each number with a name. You can make this matrix using a list comprehension

```
combinedList = [[one[x], two[x]] for x in range(len(two))]
```

output:

```
[['max', 92.11], ['allen', 88.63], ['george', 72.66], ['steve', 33.99]]
```

Then, sort the list using the 2nd item in each entry (index 1)

```
outputList = sorted(combinedList, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

output:

```
[['steve', 33.99], ['george', 72.66], ['allen', 88.63], ['max', 92.11]]
```

For further processing, you could once again split this list back into list one and two, but sorted.  Again, using list comprehension

```
one = [x[0] for x in outputList]
two = [x[1] for x in outputList]
```

output:

```
['steve', 'george', 'allen', 'max']
[33.99, 72.66, 88.63, 92.11]
```